# How do I load my script into the node.js REPL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I have a script `foo.js` that contains some functions I want to play with in the REPL.

Is there a way to have node execute my script and then jump into a REPL with all the declared globals, like I can with `python -i foo.py` or `ghci foo.hs`?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

There is still nothing built-in to provide the exact functionality you describe.  However, an alternative to using `require` it to use the [`.load` command](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_design_and_features) within the REPL, like such:

```
.load foo.js
```

It loads the file in line by line just as if you had typed it in the REPL.  Unlike `require` this pollutes the REPL history with the commands you loaded.  However, it has the advantage of being repeatable because it is not cached like `require`.

Which is better for you will depend on your use case.

---

**Edit:** It has limited applicability because it does not work in strict mode, but three years later I have learned that if your script does not have `'use strict'`, you can [use `eval` to load your script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5809968/1072626) without polluting the REPL history:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
eval(fs.readFileSync('foo.js').toString())
```

Comment: What if I want to drop into the repl inside of an async callback?

Comment: @Chet You write up a new StackOverflow question if your question does not match an existing one :-)

Comment: @Chet you can .load another file with (async()=>{ more code })(); and it will share the same globals.

Comment: Tip if you're on macOS (maybe others as well). You can type ".load " (note the space) into the REPL and drag/drop the file into the Terminal from the Finder to add the correct path to your command. This is handy if the files you're working with are several levels down.

Comment: I needed to declare `__dirname` to make it work. Also, I wrote the code into a shell script (for the sake of reusability). Otherwise, great solution!

Comment: @vossad01 and then watch it get marked as a duplicate anyway.

Answer (score 70):

i always use this command

```
node -i -e "$(< yourScript.js)"
```

works exactly as in Python without any packages.

Comment: does anyone know how to get this working in windows cmd?  I got it working in bash, but not windows.

Comment: @Sharpiro: If you install Git then you have an option to install a mini-UNIX into your Windows PC. 
I mean Git's normal distribution for Windows.

Comment: The one thing that's annoying about this is Node.js will print the repl prompt and _then_ run your script, so any output gets stuck after the prompt. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45893494/3538165 doesn't have this problem but for that solution functions must be assigned explicitly to variables to end up in the repl namespace, so not very good either.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. Super helpful. Thanks @George

Answer (score 13):

I made [Vorpal.js](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal), which handles this problem by turning your node add into an interactive CLI. It supports a REPL extension, which drops you into a REPL within the context of your running app.

```
var vorpal = require('vorpal')();
var repl = require('vorpal-repl');

vorpal
  .delimiter('myapp>')
  .use(repl)
  .show()
  .parse(process.argv);
```

Then you can run the app and it will drop into a REPL.

```
$ node myapp.js repl
myapp> repl:
```

Answer (score 12):

Another way is to define those functions as global.

```
global.helloWorld = function() { console.log("Hello World"); }
```

Then preload the file in the REPL as:

```
node -r ./file.js
```

Then the function `helloWorld` can be accessed directly in the REPL.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a bash function version of 
[George's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45781299/350761):

```bash
noderepl() {
    FILE_CONTENTS="$(< $1 )"
    node -i -e "$FILE_CONTENTS"
}
```

If you put this in your `~/.bash_profile` you can use it like an alias, i.e.:

```
noderepl foo.js
```

Comment: I've been using this for months now, and in a  transition to a new shell environment I lost some of my settings and had to track this back down again. So since I'm here, I thought I'd thank you for this really useful function.

Answer (score 8):

I created [replpad](http://thlorenz.github.io/replpad/) since I got tired of reloading the script repeatedly.

Simply install it via: `npm install -g replpad`

Then use it by running: `replpad`

If you want it to watch all files in the current and all subdirectories and pipe them into the repl when they change do: `replpad .`

Check out the videos on the site to get a better idea of how it works and learn about some other nice features that it has like these:

- **access core module docs in the repl** via the `dox()` function that is added to every core function, i.e. `fs.readdir.dox()`
- **access user module readmes in the repl** via the `dox()` function that is added to every module installed via npm,
  i.e. `marked.dox()`
- access function's **highlighted source code**, info on **where function was defined** (file, linenumber) and function
  comments and/or **jsdocs** where possible via the `src` property that is added to every function, i.e. `express.logger.src`
- **[scriptie-talkie](https://github.com/thlorenz/scriptie-talkie) support**  (see `.talk` command)
- **adds commands and keyboard shortcuts**
- **vim key bindings**
- **key map support**
- **parens matching** via match token plugin
- **appends code entered in repl back to file** via keyboard shortcut or `.append` command

See: https://github.com/thlorenz/replpad

Comment: I had to `CXX=clang++ npm install replpad` to work around the error `g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-stdlib=libc++'`

Comment: But then when I run it it fails with ```#
# Fatal error in ../deps/v8/src/api.cc, line 1248
# Check failed: !value_obj->IsJSReceiver() || value_obj->IsTemplateInfo().
#
Illegal instruction: 4```

Answer (score 7):

Why not load the file into an interactive node repl?

```
node -h
-e, --eval script          evaluate script
-i, --interactive          always enter the REPL even if stdin

node -e 'var client = require("./build/main/index.js"); console.log("Use `client` in repl")' -i
```

Then you can add to package.json scripts

```
"repl": "node -e 'var client = require(\"./build/main/index.js\"); console.log(\"Use `client` in repl\")' -i",
```

tested using node v8.1.2

Comment: why not just `node -i -r "./build/main/index.js"` ?

Answer (score 5):

Currently you can't do that directly, but you can `mylib = require('./foo.js')` in the REPL. Remember methods are exported, not declared as globals.

Comment: I find this preferable to `.load my_work.js`, despite requiring some additional `exports.working_var = ...` declarations, because the REPL barfs on some kinds of perfectly valid javascript, like multiline comments (at least with my `readline` configuration).

Answer (score 4):

`replpad` is cool, but for a quick and easy way to load a file into node, import its variables and start a repl, you can add the following code to the end of your .js file

```
if (require.main === module){
    (function() {
        var _context = require('repl').start({prompt: '$> '}).context;
        var scope = require('lexical-scope')(require('fs').readFileSync(__filename));
        for (var name in scope.locals[''] )
            _context[scope.locals[''][name]] = eval(scope.locals[''][name]);
        for (name in scope.globals.exported)
            _context[scope.globals.exported[name]] = eval(scope.globals.exported[name]);
    })();
}
```

Now if your file is `src.js`, running `node src.js` will start node, load the file, start a REPL, and copy all the objects declared as `var` at the top level as well as any exported globals.
The `if (require.main === module)` ensures that this code will not be executed if `src.js` is included through a `require` statement. I fact, you can add any code you want to be excuted when you are running `src.js` standalone for debugging purposes inside the `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Another suggestion that I do not see here: try this little bit of code

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

const repl = require('repl');
const cli = repl.start({ replMode: repl.REPL_MODE_STRICT });
cli.context.foo = require('./foo'); // injects it into the repl
```

Then you can simply run this script and it will include `foo` as a variable

Answer (score 2):

Old answer

```
type test.js|node -i
```

Will open the node REPL and type in all lines from test.js into REPL, but for some reason node will quit after file ends

Another problem is, that functions will not be hoisted.

## Better answer

```
node -e require('repl').start({useGlobal:true}); -r ./test2.js
```

Then all globals declared without var within test2.js will be available in the REPL

not sure why var a in global scope will not be available

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55347069/edit) some explanaton to your answer

Comment: Seems like `type` doesn't work in `bash`. For the better answer, seems like you can just do `node -r noderc.js` without starting the repl manually. But you have to assign to `global` directly in the script for functions/var. There should be a way to appropriate "vm.runInContext" in order to take more values from the script.

Comment: `cat` is `type` in bash/posix

Answer (score -1):

There is an Official Node.js [REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) that supports also async methods

`console.js`

```
const repl = require('repl')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const run = async () => {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })

    const r = repl.start(`(${process.env.NODE_EN}) ⚡️ `)
    r.context.User = require('./src/models/user.model')
    r.context.mongoose = mongoose
    console.log(`Ready `);
}

run()
```

Start the console:

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-repl-await node console.js
```

`User` model its exposed to console

```
await User.find({})
```

[source](https://softwarebrothers.co/blog/node-js-repl-run-js-code-within-your-app-environment/)