# Run Coffeescript Interactive (REPL) with a script

Tags: coffeescript, interactive, read-eval-print-loop

In python, I can run a script and enter interactive mode in the context of that script. This lets me mess with global variables and what not to examine program state.

```
$ python -i hello.py
```

Can I do this with Coffeescript? I've tried the following:

```
$ coffee -i hello.coffee
```

doesn't load hello.coffee. It's equivalent to coffee -i

```
$ cat hello.coffee | coffee -i
```

runs the script line by line in REPL but ends REPL after the EOF.

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/a/13386057/149330:

Use `cat hello.coffee - | coffee`

Comment: Its no t exactly what you're looking for, but how about just writing it as a module and then use ``require`` to load it in the normal repl mode?

Comment: This is the only real reason for not using coffeescript imo. one needs to be able to invoke the coffeescript repl from a script. you can use source maps n stuff but its a bit awkward

Answer (score 4):

I've recently started a project to create an advanced interactive shell for Node and associated languages like CoffeeScript. One of the features is loading a file or string in the context of the interpreter at startup which takes into account the loaded language.

http://danielgtaylor.github.com/nesh/

Example:

```
# Load a string
nesh -c -e 'hello = (name) -> "Hello, #{name}"'

# Load a file
nesh -c -e hello.coffee
```

Then in the interpreter you can access the `hello` function. Also a good idea to create an alias in bash:

```
alias cs='nesh -c'
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks for making it.

Answer (score 1):

`cat foo.coffee - | coffee -i`

tells cat to first output your code and then output stdin, which gives you what you're looking for I think.

Comment: This is pretty neat. Has the same issue that it doesn't parse multiline statements, and it requires a `process.exit()` plus a <kbd>ctrl</kdb>-<kbd>c</kbd>, but it's still a useful hack to bootstrap a few things...

Answer (score 0):

I am confronted with this problem as well. The one provide by @int3 doesn't solve this problem, for CoffeeScript is one indentation based language. stdin will pass the code line by line, but the repl is not smart enough to realize this. Since you post this question, I suggest you create one issue (feature request) on [CoffeeScript](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script)