# One line to run node script interactively?

Tags: node.js

Why can't I run `node -e ".load ./script.js"`?

```
$ node -e '.load ./script.js'
[eval]:1
.load
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at node.js:578:27
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
```

I tried escaping the `.` with a `\` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript code, what are you expecting to happen? Did you mean `require('./script.js')`?

Comment: It is valid in node's interactive mode. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15387586/903980

Comment: No, it's valid in the REPL, that's very different from interactive mode.

Comment: `$ node --interactive`, `>  .load ./script.js` works fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `-e` flag tells node to run eval on the provided string. This means it is running it as pure javascript. `.load` is a REPL command, which means it is not javascript. `-e` also does not run the REPL, so will not do what you want.

if all you want is to run the script from the command line, you can just do `node path/to/script.js`

To run a one liner that loads a script, you can do `node -e "require('path/to/script.js')"`, however this will simply load the script, then quit. node will return, and nothing will appear to happen. There are likely several ways to run a REPL with pre-loaded data, but the way I like to do it is this:

```
node -e "const repl = require('repl'); repl.start().context.script = require('path/to/script.js')"
```

I actually have this in a batch script (since I'm running windows) which I use to test libraries. I just have to pass in any scripts I want to include and it will start up the REPL for me with them loaded.