# Why can't I eval a .load to start an interactive script in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

In node.js you can pass the argument `-i` to get an interactive console, and then pass `-e` to evaluate a javascript statement.

I tried running:

```
$ node -i -e '.load ./someScript.js'
.load someScript.js;
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at node.js:578:27
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
```

And I get an error, but if I try to run the same thing from the interactive node prompt, it loads just fine; i.e.

```
> .load ./someScript.js
```

Is there something else I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Not really an answer, but why can't you run `node someScript.js`?

Comment: That doesn't load the script in interactive mode.  I tried `$ node -i './someScript.js'` if I do that it just exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I eval a .load to start an interactive script in node.js?

Because `-e` is for evaluating *JavaScript* code. The interactive REPL's commands aren't JavaScript, they're REPL interactive commands.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549145/execute-some-code-and-then-go-into-interactive-node) asks how to go interactive after running a script, which doesn't answer the "why" part (that's why I've posted the above), but its answers may give you some options for the somewhat-implied "...and what do I do instead?" part. :-)

Comment: Is there any way to load them anyway?  Or am I required to make a module and use the `-r` option?  I also tried flattening out the code I want to use and running it in a `-e`, and even with the `-i` I end up with no prompt.

Comment: @leeand00: Yeah, that's what I would have used too, also being on \*nix. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe use a custom script to initiate the REPL from its [module](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html):

Something like:

```
const repl = require('repl'),
      path = require('path'),
      location = process.argv[2],
      base = path.basename(location),
      clean = path.split('.')[0];

const r = repl.start('> ');
Object.defineProperty(r.context, clean, {
  configurable: false,
  enumerable: true,
  value: require(location)
});
```

So, now you can do `node loadModule /path/to/load.js`, the module will be available depending on the base of the path (`/path/to/load.js` will be available under `load` for example)