# Keep Node Prompt Open After a Script Has Run?

Tags: node.js

I have a JS script for Node that accepts piped data and sets it to a variable. I already did that part.

However, I'd like to have the Node command prompt stay open so I can experiment/"play with" different types of piped data before I made any future scripts, etc.

Is there any way keep a generic Node prompt open *after* a script has run?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549145/execute-some-code-and-then-go-into-interactive-node

Comment: What @Syc suggests is easier than dropping to interactive mode from a script

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Line Input Command-Line](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input/)

You can implement a while statement to retrieve an input like "quit" and end your program.