# Interacting with app code in the node REPL

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

One of the pleasures of frameworks like Rails is being able to interact with models on the command line. Being very new to node.js, I often find myself pasting chunks of app code into the REPL to play with objects. It's dirty.

Is there a magic bullet that more experienced node developers use to get access to their app specific stuff from within the `node` prompt? Would a solution be to package up the whole app, or parts of the app, into modules to be `require()`d? I'm still living in one-big-ol'-file land, so pulling everything out is, while inevitable, a little daunting.

Thanks in advance for any helpful hints you can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-big-ol'-file land is actually a good place to be in for what you want to do. Nodejs can also `require` it's REPL in the code itself, which will save you copy and pasting.

Here is a simple example from one of my projects. Near the top of your file do something similar to this:

```
function _cb() {
  console.log(arguments)
}

var repl = require("repl");
var context = repl.start("$ ").context;
context.cb = _cb;
```

Now just add to the context throughout your code. The _cb is a dummy callback to play with function calls that require one (and see what they'll return).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the REPL API has changed quite a bit, this code works for me:

```
  var replServer = repl.start({
    prompt: "node > ",
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    useGlobal: true
  });
  replServer.on('exit', function() {
    console.log("REPL DONE");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27536499/1936097. This code will automatically load a REPL if the file is run directly from node AND add all your declared methods and variables to the context automatically.