# Node REPL in Emacs printing my input

Tags: javascript, node.js, emacs, read-eval-print-loop

I am having troubles setting up some details in my node REPL:

Whenever I type a command into the prompt this command is reprinted before I get the real output from the REPL. For example:

> var n = 1;
>   var n = 1;
>   undefined

I tried to use some code from balajis repo https://github.com/startup-class/dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs.d/js-comint.el, but afterwards my M-x run-js command didn't work.

Here is my init file (I haven't edited my js-comint.el):

```
(normal-erase-is-backspace-mode 1)


(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/auto-complete/")
; Load the default configuration                                                                             
(require 'auto-complete-config)
; Make sure we can find the dictionaries                                                                     
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/auto-complete/dict")
; Use dictionaries by default                                                                                
(setq-default ac-sources (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-dictionary))
(global-auto-complete-mode t)
; Start auto-completion after 2 characters of a word                                                         
(setq ac-auto-start 2)
; case sensitivity is important when finding matches                                                         
(setq ac-ignore-case nil)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/yasnippet/")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
;; Load the snippet files themselves                                                                         
(yas/load-directory "~/.emacs.d/yasnippet/snippets/text-mode/javascript-mode/")
;; Let's have snippets in the auto-complete dropdown                                                         
(add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-yasnippet)

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist (cons (rx ".js" eos) 'js2-mode))

(require 'js-comint)
(setq inferior-js-program-command "/usr/bin/java org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main")
(setq inferior-js-program-command "node")

(setq inferior-js-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        ;; We like nice colors                                                                               
        (ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
        ;; Deal with some prompt nonsense                                                                    
        (add-to-list
         'comint-preoutput-filter-functions
         (lambda (output)
           (replace-regexp-in-string "\033\\[[0-9]+[GKCJ]" "" output)))))

(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                           (local-set-key "\C-x\C-e" 'eval-last-sexp)
                           (local-set-key "\C-cb" 'js-send-buffer)
                           (local-set-key "\C-c\C-b" 'js-send-buffer-and-go)
                           (local-set-key "\C-cl" 'js-load-file-and-go)
                           (local-set-key "\C-c!" 'run-js)
                           (local-set-key "\C-c\C-r" 'js-send-region)
                           (local-set-key "\C-c\C-j" 'js-send-line)
                           (local-set-key "\C-c\C-u" 'whitespace-clean-and-compile)
                           ))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with changing the approach to solving the problem slightly, you could use [replpad](http://thlorenz.github.io/replpad/) instead. It works with any editor, automatically updating whenever a file changes.

Simply install it via: `npm install -g replpad`

Then use it by running: `replpad`

If you want it to watch all files in the current and all subdirectories and pipe them into the repl when they change do: `replpad .`

More details [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23840336/97443)

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

```
(add-hook 'inferior-js-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq comint-process-echoes t)))
```