# Is there a way to run a JavaScript file inside the Node.js shell?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell

I am new to `Node.js` and I was wondering if there was a way of executing a `JavaScript` file from inside the Node shell. Let me explain it this way:

Instead of doing this:

`$ node file.js`

which will execute the script but will close the Node shell afterwards...

Is there a way of executing a script being already inside the Node shell? Something like:

```
$ node
> file.js                  # We're now inside the Node.js shell

... script execution...

>                          # already inside the shell, 
                           # then being able to access to script variables
```

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425102/how-do-i-load-my-script-into-the-node-js-repl

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Executing the following command inside `Node.js` Shell worked:

```
.load foo.js
```

Answer (score 2):

just do a require!

**example: file.js:**

```js
console.log( "SCRIPT RUNNING" );
module.exports = "optional return";
```

require it from the shell

```
$ node
> myresult = require( "./file.js" )
SCRIPT RUNNING
'optional return'
>
```

Comment: `.load` will load the file directly to the REPL. See the docs: 
 http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_features