# Run a JS function with arguments from the Command Line

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, cmd

I have a javascript file with a function that receives an Array with random numbers and returns a solution, I need to be able to run this function from the Command Line.

What i want is to be able to type something like:
`myFunction 1,2,3,4,5,6,7`

Comment: you could use nodejs I guess

Comment: you are saying that you need run that function from browser console right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I load my script into the node.js REPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425102/how-do-i-load-my-script-into-the-node-js-repl)

Comment: Which command line are you referencing?

Comment: @iSkore Why did you add `node.js` tag to the Question?

Comment: @guest271314, because “Command Line” refers to the Node.js execution of JavaScript.

Comment: @iSkore Not necessarily. It is possible to use `--headless` and `--repl` flags with Chromium/Chrome browsers

Comment: To call a specific file from the command line?

Comment: @iSkore Yes. Either a local file or a remote file, see [Getting Started with Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Node.js for JavaScript CLI.

You can pass arguments like this -

```
node calendar.js --year 2020 --month 7
```

Using above command `process.argv[]` array will have this value -

```
['node', 'calendar.js', '--year', '2020', '--month', '7']
```

In your code, it can be read using array `process.argv[]` like this -

```
var x = +process.argv[2];  //For third argument
var y = +process.argv[3];  //For fourth argument
```

1st and 2nd arguments will be `node` and `calendar.js` respectively

Comment: What is + in +process.argv[2]; when calling the cmd arguments?

Answer (score 1):

[Export](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) the function from your file:

```
module.exports = function myFunction(){
    // ...
}
```

and then use that exported module in your command line with Node's [REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl) by first running `node` then executing:

```
> const myFunction = require('./path/to/the/file-containing-myFunction')`
```

after which you'll be able to use `myFunction` like so:

```
> myFunction()
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering NodeJS, create a wrapper script where your script with `myFunction` is imported (would have to export it with `module.exports.myFunction = myFunction` in your original file first), then pass it the arguments from `process.args`, skipping the 1st element (as it's always path of the script):

```
// argsrun.js
var myFunction = require('thescript.js').myFunction;
myFunction(process.args.slice(2));
```

and call it from CLI:

```
node argsrun.js 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: `process.args` should be `process.argv`

Answer (score 0):

The demo

```
'use strict';

function add( n1, n2 ) {
    return n1 + n2;
}

function subtract( n1, n2 ) {
    return n1 - n2;
}
```

#### On browser:

Invoke the function calling:

```
window.add( 1, 2 );
window.subtract( 1, 2 );
```

#### With Node.js:

Invoke the function from the command line:

> **Note: this is only for development purposes**
>
> **Do not use `eval` in production**

Put this at the bottom of the file:

`eval( process.argv[ 2 ] )`

And call your function by doing:

```
node index.js "add( 1, 2 )"
node index.js "subtract( 1, 2 )"
```

with your terminal