# ST3 Build System : prevent Node.js to come back to prompt after execution

Tags: node.js, windows, sublimetext3

When I execute a script with Node.js in command prompt lets say like that :

```
c:\> node a_script.js
```

It just exits when the script is ended which is boring because I d'like to test some variables values. I can't find any option using `node --help` to avoid that, do you know a way ?

I want to do a Sublime Text Build System

```
{
    "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "C:/progra~2/nodejs/node.exe", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.js",
    "shell" : true
}
```

My script is executed but it exit just after. I expect to go back to REPL but `node.exe` closes once it has executed my script.

The solutions provided by the following  question didn't worked : 
[How do I load my script into the node.js REPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425102/how-do-i-load-my-script-into-the-node-js-repl?noredirect=1&lq=1)  since most of the time it implies to type some command in the REPL

I also tried to use `--interactive` but no luck.

Comment: 1. Run node. 2. Type `.load a_script.js` 3. Do whatever else you want at the REPL.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425102/how-do-i-load-my-script-into-the-node-js-repl

Comment: in fact, and to be more precise, I avoided to explain that I wanted to do a build system for Sublime text but I will edit my question because it has sens now

Comment: It was at the time of my vote. Now it isn't, but the other question is still at least relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by installing `replpad` with `npm`

```
npm install -g replpad
```

And using the following build system :

```
{
    "shell" : true, 
    "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "replpad", "$file_path"], 
}
```

that's a bit weird is that I need to save the file once `replpad` has been loaded but it works