# Inspect an Express.js app that uses import

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

I have an app that contains the following in `index.js`:

```
import express from 'express';
import data from './data/data.json';

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
```

How can I access the `data` variable for testing purposes?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45781299/1417223) given on SO (`node -i -e "$(< index.js)"`) returns the following error:

```
import express from 'express';
        ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I'm on Node 10.8 and Express 4.16.3.

In Rails, you're given an interactive console (by running `rails console`) where you can "play around" with the environment (db et al).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because that import statement come later so not get identified by compilers/browsers.
You can use babel as transpiler https://babeljs.io/
 or
try this

```
var express = require('express');
var data = require('./data/data.json');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
```

**Edit**

---

Make your package.json file look like this (install packages and change script by adding babel-node)

```
    {.....
      "scripts": {
      ....
      "start": "babel-node Server.js"
      ...  
   },
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-core": "6.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
     .....}
```

---

create **.babelrc** file in root directory on project (where node_modules of project are)

```
{
"presets": ["react","es2015"],
"env": {
    "development": {
                                    "presets": [
                                                            "react-hmre"
                                                            ]
                                }
                }
}
```

and run

```
npm start
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a suggestion how I would use babel as a transpiler to get the import working?

Comment: @ Fellow Stranger are you using node.js?

Comment: Yes, I'm on Node 10.8 and Express 4.16.3.

Comment: hold my bear, let me try.

Comment: @ Fellow Stranger I edit the ans. You can now use import in your project. If still any error then ask

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const data = require('./data/data.json');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
```

I think this should work.