# Does running node console in a node.js project load all of the dependencies in package.json?

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js and realized I can type `node` into the terminal and load up a console (although I'm not sure if console is the right term here). I am wondering if when I start up this console, it loads into memory all of the dependencies I have defined in `package.json`? Also - how is it different than, for instance, starting the node.js environment with `yarn start` or `npm start`? Is the entry point different when I just type in `node` into the terminal?

Comment: when you run npm start it will run script that is written in package.json. Sometimes that script can be same as calling file with node, but sometimes if will have additional arguments or so.

Comment: as for your question, dependencies are not imported from package.json, package.json is just for tracking dependencies that are stored in node modules and then you import it in file from node moduls folder. So yes your code will work if you run  node filename.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're loading when you just type `node` is the node [REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html), which stands for **Read, Evaluate, Print, Loop**. Think of this like an interactive node terminal; "console" is also a good term for it, imo.

It does not automatically load a project's package.json into the REPL when you launch it. You would have to use the [.load command](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_design_and_features) to do that. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22817680/2575069) on a similar question goes into a bit more detail.