# How could import my modules to nodejs command line?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on nodejs' command line and intend to import a script named "code-chapter-5.js" as it works in python:

```
import * from code-chapter-5.js
```

Searched through and got a solution as:

```
.load ./code-chapter-5.js
```

It works:

```
> pair(1,3)
[ 1, 3 ]
> is_pair(pair(1, 3))
true
```

but report error:

```
Thrown:
ReferenceError: apply_in_underlying_javascript is not defined
    at arg_list (repl:48:142)
    at perform_make_operation_exp (repl:485:2557)
    at perform_make_test (repl:351:2085)
    at execute (repl:165:1035)
    at message.start (repl:171:1148)
    at start (repl:191:1306)
```

Since the referenced question was answered 6 years ago [How do I load my script into the node.js REPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425102/how-do-i-load-my-script-into-the-node-js-repl)

What's the decent solution now?

Comment: `apply_in_underlying_javascript` is not a fn you wrote or that code-chapter-5.js contains, is it?

Comment: ty and I got your idea. @weltschmerz

Comment: I didn't suggest any ideas, I just asked a question. Can you answer the question?

Comment: @weltschmerz No, it is not defined.

Comment: Right, but does either your code or the code in code-chapter-5.js contain some reference called "apply_in_underlying_javascript"?

Comment: ty, I know how to solve the problem. @weltschmerz

Comment: Ok what's the solution?