# What is "strict mode" and how is it used?

Tags: javascript, strict-mode

I've been looking over the JavaScript reference on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDN_Web_Docs), and I came across something called `"strict mode"`. I read it over and I'm having trouble understanding what it does. Can someone briefly explain (in general) what its purpose is and how it is useful?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1335851/1461424

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Its main purpose is to do more checking.

Just add `"use strict";` at the top of your code, before anything else.

For example, `blah = 33;` is valid JavaScript. It means you create a completely global variable `blah`.

But in strict mode it's an error because you did not use the keyword "var" to declare the variable.

*Most of the time* you don't mean to create global variables in the middle of some arbitrary scope, so most of the time that `blah = 33` is written it is an error and the programmer didn't actually want it to be a global variable, they meant to write `var blah = 33`.

It similarly disallows a lot of things that are technically valid to do. `NaN = "lol"` does not produce an error. It also doesn't change the value of NaN. Using strict this (and similar weird statements) produce errors. Most people appreciate this because there is no reason to ever write `NaN = "lol"`, so there was most likely a typo.

[Read more at the MDN page on strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Comment: this is an exact duplicate of the documentation over at MDN

Comment: What don't you understand about its utility then? It aims to help development by catching things that are valid-but-most-likely-errors.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Using strict this"*?

Answer (score 35):

One aspect of strict mode not already mentioned in Simon's answer is that strict mode sets `this` to `undefined` in functions invoked through function invocation.

So things like this

```
function Obj() {
   this.a = 12;
   this.b = "a";
   this.privilegedMethod = function () {
      this.a++;
      privateMethod();
   };

   function privateMethod() {
     this.b = "foo";
   }
}
```

will cause an error when `privateMethod` is called (since you can't add a property to `undefined`), rather than uselessly adding a `b` property to the global object.

Comment: yeah need to add `privateMethod.bind(this)();` and call with `new` [`jsbin.com`](https://jsbin.com/foyomo/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: Most important restrictions in strict mode: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/advanced/strict-mode-javascript#restrictions-on-code-in-strict-mode

Answer (score 23):

Strict mode was added so that there would be an easily statically-analyzable subset of [ECMAScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) which would be a good target for future versions of the language.  Strict mode was also designed in the hope that developers who limit themselves to strict mode would make fewer mistakes and that the bugs they do make would manifest in more obvious ways.

[Harmony](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:harmony), which will hopefully become the next major version of ECMAScript is going to be built on top of ES5 strict.

> Harmony builds on ES5 strict mode to avoid too many modes.

Some other language experiments also depend on strict mode. [SES](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=ses:ses) depends on ES5 strict mode's analyzability.

> SES (Secure ECMAScript) Design Experiment
>
> Design an Object Capability Programming Language by removing or repairing features in ES5/Strict.
>
> There should be a straight-forward translation from SES to ES5/Strict.

[Annex C](http://es5.github.com/#C) of the standard explains the differences between strict mode and normal mode.

> The strict mode restriction and exceptions
>
> - The identifiers "implements", "interface", "let", "package", "private", "protected", "public", "static", and "yield" are classified as FutureReservedWord tokens within strict mode code. (7.6.12 [?]).
> - A conforming implementation, when processing strict mode code, may not extend the syntax of NumericLiteral (7.8.3) to include OctalIntegerLiteral as described in B.1.1.
> - A conforming implementation, when processing strict mode code (see 10.1.1), may not extend the syntax of EscapeSequence to include OctalEscapeSequence as described in B.1.2.
> - Assignment to an undeclared identifier or otherwise unresolvable reference does not create a property in the global object. When a simple assignment occurs within strict mode code, its LeftHandSide must not evaluate to an unresolvable Reference. If it does a ReferenceError exception is thrown (8.7.2). The LeftHandSide also may not be a reference to a data property with the attribute value {[[Writable]]:false}, to an accessor property with the attribute value {[[Set]]:undefined}, nor to a non-existent property of an object whose [[Extensible]] internal property has the value false. In these cases a TypeError exception is thrown (11.13.1).
> - The identifier eval or arguments may not appear as the LeftHandSideExpression of an Assignment operator (11.13) or of a PostfixExpression (11.3) or as the UnaryExpression operated upon by a Prefix Increment (11.4.4) or a Prefix Decrement (11.4.5) operator.
>   Arguments objects for strict mode functions define non-configurable accessor properties named "caller" and "callee" which throw a TypeError exception on access (10.6).
> - Arguments objects for strict mode functions do not dynamically share their array indexed property values with the corresponding formal parameter bindings of their functions. (10.6).
>   For strict mode functions, if an arguments object is created the binding of the local identifier arguments to the arguments object is immutable and hence may not be the target of an assignment expression. (10.5).
> - It is a SyntaxError if strict mode code contains an ObjectLiteral with more than one definition of any data property (11.1.5).
>   It is a SyntaxError if the Identifier "eval" or the Identifier "arguments" occurs as the Identifier in a PropertySetParameterList of a PropertyAssignment that is contained in strict code or if its FunctionBody is strict code (11.1.5).
> - Strict mode eval code cannot instantiate variables or functions in the variable environment of the caller to eval. Instead, a new variable environment is created and that environment is used for declaration binding instantiation for the eval code (10.4.2).
> - If this is evaluated within strict mode code, then the this value is not coerced to an object. A this value of null or undefined is not converted to the global object and primitive values are not converted to wrapper objects. The this value passed via a function call (including calls made using Function.prototype.apply and Function.prototype.call) do not coerce the passed this value to an object (10.4.3, 11.1.1, 15.3.4.3, 15.3.4.4).
> - When a delete operator occurs within strict mode code, a SyntaxError is thrown if its UnaryExpression is a direct reference to a variable, function argument, or function name(11.4.1).
> - When a delete operator occurs within strict mode code, a TypeError is thrown if the property to be deleted has the attribute { [[Configurable]]:false } (11.4.1).
>   It is a SyntaxError if a VariableDeclaration or VariableDeclarationNoIn occurs within strict code and its Identifier is eval or arguments (12.2.1).
> - Strict mode code may not include a WithStatement. The occurrence of a WithStatement in such a context is an SyntaxError (12.10).
> - It is a SyntaxError if a TryStatement with a Catch occurs within strict code and the Identifier of the Catch production is eval or arguments (12.14.1)
> - It is a SyntaxError if the identifier eval or arguments appears within a FormalParameterList of a strict mode FunctionDeclaration or FunctionExpression (13.1)
> - A strict mode function may not have two or more formal parameters that have the same name. An attempt to create such a function using a FunctionDeclaration, FunctionExpression, or Function constructor is a SyntaxError (13.1, 15.3.2).
> - An implementation may not extend, beyond that defined in this specification, meanings within strict mode functions of properties named caller or arguments of function instances. ECMAScript code may not create or modify properties with these names on function objects that correspond to strict mode functions (10.6, 13.2, 15.3.4.5.3).
> - It is a SyntaxError to use within strict mode code the identifiers eval or arguments as the Identifier of a FunctionDeclaration or FunctionExpression or as a formal parameter name (13.1). Attempting to dynamically define such a strict mode function using the Function constructor (15.3.2) will throw a SyntaxError exception.

Answer (score 7):

> ECMAScript 5 introduced the concept of *strict mode*.

**Invoking Strict Mode in Code**

Strict mode applies to entire scripts or to individual function. It doesn’t apply to block statement enclosed in {} braces, attempting to apply it to such contexts does nothing.

**Entire Script:**

Let’s say we are creating app.js, so adding the first statement use script will enforce strict mode for the entire code.

```
// app.js whole script in strict mode syntax
“use strict”;
// Now you can start writing your code
```

**Strict mode for function:**

To *invoke* strict mode for a function, put the exact statement “use strict”; at the start of the function body before any other statement.

```
function yourFunc(){
    "use strict";

    // Your function code logic
}
```

Strict mode incorporate several changes to normal JavaScript semantics. First, strict mode eliminates some JavaScript silent errors by changing them to throw errors.

**For Instance: Code using Strict Mode**

[image]

In the above code example, without using strict mode in code, it won't throw an error. As we are accessing variable `x` without declaring it. So in strict mode accessing undeclared variables throws an error.

Now let's try to access a variable, x, without declaring it without strict mode.

```
(function(){
    x = 3;
})();

// Will not throw an error
```

**Advantage of using strict mode:**

- Eliminate JavaScript silent errors by throwing errors.
- Fixes mistakes that make it difficult for JavaScript engine to perform optimisation.
- Make code sometimes run faster than identical code that’s not in strict mode
- Prohibits some syntax likely to be defined in future version of ECMAScript.

Answer (score 6):

Strict mode makes several changes to normal JavaScript semantics.

- strict mode eliminates some JavaScript silent errors by changing them to throw errors.
- strict mode fixes mistakes that make it difficult for JavaScript engines to perform optimizations.
- strict mode prohibits some syntax likely to be defined in future versions of ECMAScript.

Answer (score 2):

`ECMAScript5` introduces some new objects and properties and also the so-called `"strict mode"`.

Strict mode is a subset of the language that excludes deprecated features. The strict
mode is opt-in and not required, meaning that if you want your code to run in the
strict mode, you declare your intention using (once per function, or once for the
whole program) the following string:

```
"use strict";
```

Comment: Isn't it more than a subset? Like checking for undefined variables?

Answer (score 2):

2017 and I finally found the documentation: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

> Strict mode is a way to opt in to a restricted variant of JavaScript.
>   Strict mode isn't just a subset: it intentionally has different
>   semantics from normal code. Browsers not supporting strict mode will
>   run strict mode code with different behavior from browsers that do, so
>   don't rely on strict mode without feature-testing for support for the
>   relevant aspects of strict mode. Strict mode code and non-strict mode
>   code can coexist, so scripts can opt into strict mode incrementally.

> Strict mode makes several changes to normal JavaScript semantics.
>   First, strict mode eliminates some JavaScript silent errors by
>   changing them to throw errors. Second, strict mode fixes mistakes that
>   make it difficult for JavaScript engines to perform optimizations:
>   strict mode code can sometimes be made to run faster than identical
>   code that's not strict mode. Third, strict mode prohibits some syntax
>   likely to be defined in future versions of ECMAScript.

Answer (score 1):

Strict mode is a new feature in ECMAScript 5 that allows Developers to put the code inside the "strict" context.
This strict context helps developers to avoid errors by throwing more exceptions.

**How to use Strict mode in js?**

Simple. Toss this at the top of a program to enable it for the whole script:

```
"use strict";
```

Or place it within a function to turn on strict mode only within that context.

```
function imStrict(){
  "use strict";
  // … your code (executes in strict mode) …
}
```

**Advantages of Using Strict mode in JS**

**1 . Functions are Block scope inside a Block**
Scope determines the visibility or accessibility of a variable or other resource in the area of your code

*Case I (without strict mode)*
[image]

*Case II (strict mode)*
[image]

**2 . Throws error/exception if variables are assigned a value but not defined any type**
[image]
In the above example "a" is not declared any value (let, const, var)

**3. Throws an error if any reserved variables is used locally**
Keywords reserved for future JavaScript versions can NOT be used as variable names in strict mode.

These are:
public
implements
interface
let
package
private
protected
static
yield
For eg, [image]

**4. "this" inside the simple function points to "undefined" in strict mode.
The "this" keyword refers to the object that is called the function.**
If the object is not specified, functions in strict mode will return undefined and functions in normal mode will return the global object (window)
Below are the examples for better understanding

*Case I (without strict mode)*
[image]

*Case II (strict mode)*
[image]

**5. Deleting a variable (or object) and a function is not allowed.**
[image]

**6. Duplicating a parameter name is not allowed**
[image]

The body of a class is executed in strict mode, by default.
for eg:

```
class Rectangle {
//code executed here are in Strict mode
}
```

**References**

1. [John Resig](https://johnresig.com/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/)
2. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)
3. [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp)

Answer (score 0):

**Question:**

Following is the problem I encountered. I was following a tutorial and it ended up trying to compile the following `scss` file and trying to generate CSS code from it,

```
.fatty{
  width: percentage(6/7);
}
```

using the following `gulpfile.js` task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/scss/styles.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
});
```

So the error I'm getting is as follows:

```
~/htdocs/Learning/gulp1/node_modules/gulp-sass/index.js:66
    let sassMap;
    ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
// stacktrace here...
```

**Solution:**

So it shows me the `index.js` file which is inside my gulp-sass module (which is basically locked and shouldn't be edited). But if I go forcefully and add the `"use_strict"` on the top of that `index.js` file, it runs my task smoothly.

I was helpless, so I kept using this as the solution! But then after going through some other Stack Overflow [Q&As, I saw the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47156553/1752988) as follows:

```
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

And as soon as I updated my Node.js (to version 10.x), and then rebuilt Gulp by running the following commands as Terminal, it instructed me:

```
npm rebuild node-sass --force
```

And it's all okay. So that's how it got resolved. I have undone the changes I did for the `index.js` Gulp.js module file. And now it runs smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

To build upon the answers on how to use the strict mode. If you are using [ES Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), the code always runs in strict mode and cannot be disabled. So you don't need to use `"use strict"` in your code anymore.

The following is a quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#other_differences_between_modules_and_standard_scripts):

> Also, note that you might get different behavior from sections of script defined inside modules as opposed to in standard scripts. This is because modules use strict mode automatically.