# Meteor won't start. "Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode" in ejson.js

Tags: windows, meteor, use-strict

I'm new to Meteor, and only trying to install and get a new app running.  I had things were working last Friday, but had to reinstall today and can no longer get the app running.

The install has been a challenge.  Trying to install on Windows, and have found the installers just don't work.  Resorted to extracting a tar.gz file.  Also, due to company restrictions, had to install to an alternate location (the default in %LocalAppData% is locked down by policy).  But, as I said, this was working last week, but can't get it working today.  Others on the team started seeing this, this week too.  When running `meteor` for the first time, it updates to meteor-tool to 1.5.2.2, then updates various packages.  The ejson package is one, and is updated to 1.0.14.  If I run `meteor update` it says project is already at 1.5.2.2. (the latest) and top-level dependencies are at their latest compatible versions.  How do I fix this?  Thanks!

Console Output:

```
C:\dev\R&D\meteor\meteor-test>meteor
[[[[[ C:\dev\R&D\meteor\meteor-test ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
W20171020-14:19:35.920(-5)? (STDERR) C:\dev\R&D\meteor\meteor-test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\packages\ejson.js:749
W20171020-14:19:36.013(-5)? (STDERR)       for (let i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
W20171020-14:19:36.016(-5)? (STDERR)            ^^^
W20171020-14:19:36.018(-5)? (STDERR)
W20171020-14:19:36.019(-5)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
W20171020-14:19:36.021(-5)? (STDERR)     at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
W20171020-14:19:36.022(-5)? (STDERR)     at C:\dev\R&D\meteor\meteor-test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:332:30
W20171020-14:19:36.023(-5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20171020-14:19:36.025(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\dev\programs\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.5.2_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_b
undle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
W20171020-14:19:36.026(-5)? (STDERR)     at C:\dev\R&D\meteor\meteor-test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:158:5
W20171020-14:19:36.028(-5)? (STDERR)     at C:\dev\R&D\meteor\meteor-test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:388:5
W20171020-14:19:36.029(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (C:\dev\R&D\meteor\meteor-test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\profile.js:510:12)
W20171020-14:19:36.031(-5)? (STDERR)     at C:\dev\R&D\meteor\meteor-test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:387:11
=> Exited with code: 1
W20171020-14:19:40.739(-5)? (STDERR) C:\dev\R&D\meteor\meteor-test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\packages\ejson.js:749
W20171020-14:19:40.741(-5)? (STDERR)       for (let i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
W20171020-14:19:40.745(-5)? (STDERR)            ^^^
W20171020-14:19:40.752(-5)? (STDERR)
W20171020-14:19:40.754(-5)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
W20171020-14:19:40.756(-5)? (STDERR)     at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
W20171020-14:19:40.757(-5)? (STDERR)     at C:\dev\R&D\meteor\meteor-test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:332:30
W20171020-14:19:40.759(-5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20171020-14:19:40.762(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\dev\programs\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.5.2_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_b
undle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
W20171020-14:19:40.765(-5)? (STDERR)     at C:\dev\R&D\meteor\meteor-test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:158:5
W20171020-14:19:40.767(-5)? (STDERR)     at C:\dev\R&D\meteor\meteor-test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:388:5
W20171020-14:19:40.769(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (C:\dev\R&D\meteor\meteor-test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\profile.js:510:12)
W20171020-14:19:40.771(-5)? (STDERR)     at C:\dev\R&D\meteor\meteor-test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:387:11
=> Exited with code: 1
W20171020-14:19:45.026(-5)? (STDERR) C:\dev\R&D\meteor\meteor-test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\packages\ejson.js:749
W20171020-14:19:45.028(-5)? (STDERR)       for (let i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
W20171020-14:19:45.030(-5)? (STDERR)            ^^^
W20171020-14:19:45.031(-5)? (STDERR)
W20171020-14:19:45.033(-5)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
W20171020-14:19:45.034(-5)? (STDERR)     at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
W20171020-14:19:45.036(-5)? (STDERR)     at C:\dev\R&D\meteor\meteor-test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:332:30
W20171020-14:19:45.037(-5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20171020-14:19:45.039(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\dev\programs\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.5.2_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_b
undle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
W20171020-14:19:45.042(-5)? (STDERR)     at C:\dev\R&D\meteor\meteor-test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:158:5
W20171020-14:19:45.043(-5)? (STDERR)     at C:\dev\R&D\meteor\meteor-test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:388:5
W20171020-14:19:45.045(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (C:\dev\R&D\meteor\meteor-test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\profile.js:510:12)
W20171020-14:19:45.047(-5)? (STDERR)     at C:\dev\R&D\meteor\meteor-test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:387:11
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: By guess, I'd say that your javascript engine (meteor?) is not using the latest javascript.  Look for a way to tell meteor to use the latest JavaScript version.

Comment: Did you run `meteor npm install` before running `meteor` in your app folder?

Comment: Yes.  I did that already.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful about syntax when writing code in Meteor. Although Meteor runs ontop of Node.JS, it runs on an older version (Meteor `1.5` is bundled with NodeJs `v4.8.x` for instance) than most NodeJS projects (NodeJS`6.x` is considered LTS).

In your case, it looks like you are using `let` inside of a `for` loop.  It doesn't look like this syntax is supported until NodeJS `7.x` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960142/block-scoped-declarations-not-yet-supported-outside-strict-mode-laravel-mix)).  Instead, use `var` (which is the older Javascript standard).

When working with Meteor, I would highly suggest using a pre-compiled language (like `Typescript`), as it enables you to use modern syntax which will be compatible with later versions of Meteor (Node `8.x` will be a part of Meteor `1.6`).

Comment: Unfortunately, the syntax in error is inside a dependent package (ejson), and is a problem after simply running `meteor create meteor-test` from the command line - not any code of my own.  I understand what you are saying, and the error message(s) support that claim, but if that is, in fact, true, that implies Meteor is broken (at least on Windows).