# node.js basic file upload expess-fileupload error

Tags: node.js, express

Using example at [express-fileupload Examples](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload/tree/master/example#basic-file-upload)

```
<pre>   
const express = require('express');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const app = express();

// default options
app.use(fileUpload());

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
 if (Object.keys(req.files).length == 0) {
 return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
}

// The name of the input field (i.e. "sampleFile") is used to retrieve the uploaded file
```

let sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;

```
// Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server
sampleFile.mv('/somewhere/on/your/server/filename.jpg', function(err) {
 if (err)
 return res.status(500).send(err);

 res.send('File uploaded!');
 });
 }); <code>
```

I get this error

nodejs server1.js
/var/www/html/express/server1.js:14
  let sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;
  ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Something simple I'm sure. Even pasting the code here the 'let' statement is isolated.

Comment: You're using a relatively old version of Node.js. Try updating it, or add this as first line to your script: `'use strict';` (including the quotes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Block-scoped declarations not yet supported outside strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960142/block-scoped-declarations-not-yet-supported-outside-strict-mode)

Comment: That worked. I'm using nodejs -v v4.8.2.  Unfortunately now I'm getting Error: Cannot find module 'express-fileupload'  Why do these developer examples fail so frequently.

Comment: I finally got a good update. # Using Debian, as root
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs

Answer (score 0):

On the block-scoped declaration, the `let` keyword tells NodeJS that the variable you are declaring will only exist within the innermost control block of code. This may be a function or a set of curly braces within a function, most frequently seen in loops. It is not supported in early versions of node. Look into the `nvm` tool to learn how to switch between different versions of node as necessary. Usually you will want to use the latest long-term-support version.

On `cannot find module`, you are looking for the `npm` tool, which is used to install node modules. It cannot find `express-fileupload`, so you want to install that file from npm. You can install the module with:

```
npm install express-fileupload
```

Or with the shorthand `npm i express-fileupload`

If you happen to be using a really old version of npm, it is better practice to use

```
npm i express-fileupload --save
```

This will store the face that your project is dependent on the `express-fileupload` package in a file called package.json, so that npm knows this later for dependency management such as re-installation of packages, auditing, or installing dependencies when you deploy to other systems. Newer versions of npm do this automatically. You would use `npm i express-fileupload --save-dev` if you only cared about this dependency in a development environment, and not in a production environment.