# How to split a single Node.js file into separate modules

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to split the code into different files. I currently write all `get` and `post` methods in the same file, but I want greater readability and manageability.

I've tried to put the code in different files, but while running the main app, the rest of `get` and `post` methods in other files are not able to called.
I include this:

> var Db = require('/filename.js');
>   // ...but I can't call those methods.

I want to split my single file code for readability. How do I achieve this?

Comment: That's quite [simple](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

Comment: @elmigranto May I ask you why you answer questions in the comments? I see this very often, but I think Stackoverflow does not want this: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment. Sorry, I'm just curious for the reasons.

Comment: @SebastianG Because I'm not answering, but commenting :) Don't think that link or asking for more precise definition or brief statement on topic deserves separate answer (even if combined). I do answer from time to time when I feel like writing sample code and/or searching and providing some links very relevant to the question.

Comment: I think you (like me) are looking for a sort of PHP's `require` to just append code to your main js file. Have a look at many answers here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/28066576/382515](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28066576/382515)

Answer (score 21):

Just have a look at the [module documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules):

Starting with / looks for absolute paths, eg:

```
require('/home/user/module.js');
```

./ starts with the path where the calling file is located.

```
require('./lib/module.js');
```

__dirname has the same effect than ./:

```
require( __dirname + '/module.js');
```

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
var Db = require('./filename.js');
```

or

```
var Db = require('filename.js');
```

Also, have a look at this [blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-Where-Does-Node-js-And-Require-Look-For-Modules-.htm).