# call a function from one file in node.js

Tags: node.js

i have a file named `test2.js` created a function inside it

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');   
var jobScedule = function(time, jobid) {
  schedule.scheduleJob(time, function(jobid){

console.log("scheduling starts");
});

}
exports.jobScedule = jobScedule;
```

in `test1.js` i have to call this function.

```
var objTest2 = require("./Test2.js");
var time = new Date();
var jobid=10;
objTest.jobScedule(time,jobid)

console.log(time);
console.log(jobid);
```

i dont know to call function from another file in node.js.rectify me

Comment: I think the filename for the require is case sensitive.  Check your case and spelling.  Also, try removing the leading ./ in the require if everything is in the same directory.

Comment: Your `objTest` should be `objTest2` in test1.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Node.js, how do I "include" functions from my other files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var objTest= require("./Test2.js");

    var time = new Date();
    var jobid=10;
    objTest.jobScedule(time,jobid)

    console.log(time);
    console.log(jobid);
```

Answer (score 2):

In 'user.js', contains functions to be exported like

```
module.exports = {
  func1: function () {
    // func1 
  },
  func2: function () {
    // func2 
  }
};
```

In the other admin.js files, you can include the 'user.js' by

```
const user = require('./user');
```

In the following code, the exported funct1 can be like

```
user.func1();
```