# Can I run sailsjs controller methods from the command line?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am writing an application with Sailsjs which includes a scraper. Currently I'm calling the scraper functions from the browser using the default Routes but I think it would be better if I can privately call the needed methods from the terminal. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Not without external tools. [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) has this functionality, and you can import Sailsjs by checking out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Sails console to access controller methods, but you'd have to either provide fake `req` and `res` objects as arguments, or create controller functions which didn't require `req` and `res`, which isn't good practice.  A better approach would be to move the scraping code into a [*service*](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Services), which is a library that Sails makes globally available for you.  For example, if you had a file `/api/services/ScraperService.js` with:

```
module.exports = {

   scrape: function (url, fileToSaveResultsTo) {
      // do scraping and save to file
   }

}
```

then you could call the service from within a controller *or* in the Sails console with:

```
ScraperService.scrape("http://google.com", "results.txt");
```

Start the console in your terminal with `sails console`.

Comment: The link is broken. Probably referring to this: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/concepts/Services/Services.md