# How to import all tasks from another gulp file.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Is it possible to have one main gulpfile.js from which to call tasks from other gulp files.js? Simple "require" of child gulpfile.js into main one doesn't work.
I have a platform project which includes several sub projects with separate gulpfiles, so I need a solution to manage all child gulpfiles from within main one

Comment: Using `require` to import other gulpfiles should work. What errors are you seeing?

Comment: You're right it works but in form of: `var childGulp = require('./../path')();` Then I should assign `parentGulp.tasks = childGulp.tasks;`. Now console.log(parentGulp), shows childGulp's tasks.

Comment: Were you able to fix this. I am also running into same issue and have to do `var gulp = require('gulp');` and then `gulp.tasks = require('./path')().tasks;`

Comment: If you have a moment, please consider changing the selected answer to [Jonatan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67115709/1992129). I commented on his answer highlighting gulp supports and encourages splitting (with a link to gulp) -- even though gulps documentation lacked, I was able to follow Jonatan's answer to import tasks into a central gulp file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> And what if I want to make it future-proof and don't want to install
> another package for it.

The following works for me with gulp 4, *without* any extra plugins.

In `taskfile.js`:

```
const { src, dest } = require('gulp');

const mytask = function () {
  return src('assets/**/*')
    .pipe(dosomething())
    .pipe(dest('dest');
}

module.exports = {
  mytask
}
```

In `gulpfile.js`:

```
const { mytask } = require('taskfile.js');

// use in other tasks
gulp.task('manythings', gulp.series(..., mytask, ...));

// or use directly as 'gulp mytask'
module.exports = {
  mytask
}
```

Comment: Although [the selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26532942/1992129) is/was a functional answer, this answer appears to be the correct answer for the current in that [gulp supports and encourages splitting up gulp files natively](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/javascript-and-gulpfiles#splitting-a-gulpfile).

Comment: Adding to that, I had no issues following this logic and incorporating all my gulpfiles/tasks from those files into a single main gulpfile at the root. I like how this required no additional dependencies.

Answer (score 31):

It is possible to have one main gulpfile.js from which to call tasks from other gulp files.js  using the [`require-dir`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/split-tasks-across-multiple-files.md) module.  From the projects README use it like this:

---

## Split tasks across multiple files

If your `gulpfile.js` is starting to grow too large, you can split the tasks
into separate files by using the [require-dir](https://github.com/aseemk/requireDir)
module.

Imagine the following file structure:

```
gulpfile.js
tasks/
├── dev.js
├── release.js
└── test.js
```

Install the `require-dir` module:

```
npm install --save-dev require-dir
```

Add the following lines to your `gulpfile.js` file.

```
var requireDir = require('require-dir');
var dir = requireDir('./tasks');
```

Comment: And what if I want to make it future-proof and don't want to install another package for it. So for example I just want to use taskList = require('fs').readdirSync(taskPath), then creating a single function to get every task files with gulp, plugins (which for I use gulp-load-plugins), config dependencies. How can I call one task in a task file from another task file? Or how can I include it?

Comment: If there is a task test in test.js. How do I call that task? dir.test?

Answer (score 7):

I've create a special [gulp-require-tasks](https://github.com/betsol/gulp-require-tasks) module that will help you to split your `gulpfile.js` into separate smaller task files. Please see the [README](https://github.com/betsol/gulp-require-tasks) for example and documentation.

Please consider using it and let me know if it works for you! If you have any suggestions or ideas for improvement, I will gladly accept them.

Comment: See also `gulp-hub`

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend this answer for anyone who doesn't want to include a separate module or refactoring:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5809968/40769

```
var fs = require('fs');

// file is included here:
eval(fs.readFileSync('tools.js')+'');
```