# Task 'default' is not in your gulpfile after npm link gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I´m using gulp and defined my gulp task in the gulpfile.js
Because i don´t want to install gulp every time i used the

```
npm install gulp -g
npm link gulp
```

( the link command in my directory where i want to execute gulp )
after that the command "gulp" is available on my working directory, but it outputs:

> Task 'default' is not in your gulpfile
>   Blockquote

If I put a console log in the beginning of my gulpfile.js, I can see that he outputs the log and can find the gulpfile.js

Can anyone tell me where my problem is ?

I found this article but it did not helped me
[How to fix "Task is not in your gulpfile" error when using npm link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972330/task-is-not-in-your-gulpfile-when-using-npm-link)

Thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems.

**1. The misuse of npm link**

What does **npm link** do?

> it first creates a global link, and then links the global installation
>   target into your project's node_modules folder.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

So if you want to install a package globally, don't use **npm link**, because it will create a global link pointing to your local *node_modules* folder.

**2. No default task in your gulpfile**

If you want to use the **gulp** command without parameters (so you want a default behaviour), then you should specify this task. *For example:*

```javascript
// The default task (called when you run `gulp` from cli)
gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'scripts', 'images']);
```

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp#sample-gulpfilejs