# "ReferenceError: <functionName> is not defined" : libraries issue?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, jsdom

I'am very, very new to node.js and I'am likely to ask a quite easy questions.

**Client side:** I've been able to make good [maps on client side](https://rugger-demast.codio.io/1.2_location_map/index.html) via d3js, based on a custom made `./js/wikiatlas.js` ([here](https://rugger-demast.codio.io/js/wikiatlas.js)).

**Server side:** i now want to move this map generation server side. I was successful outputing a basic square.svg using node, jsdom, and d3js. I now want to use more complex functions from `./js/wikiatlas.js`. So I naively added the `./js/wikiatlas.js` dependency and the js function call `locationMap("body",800, target, title, WEST, NORTH, EAST, SOUTH);` expecting it to work (the other things works for sure). My full code:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var fs    = require('fs');
jsdom.env(
  "<html><body></body></html>",        // CREATE DOM HOOK:
  [ '../js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js', 
  '../js/d3.v3.min.js', 
  '../js/topojson.v1.min.js', 
  '../js/wikiatlas.js',             // <<======== my code (IMPORTANT !!)
  '../js/b64.js'],                  // ... & offline
//'http://rugger-demast.codio.io/js/wikiatlas.js',
  function (err, window) {
/* COLLECT ENV.VARIABLES ******************************************* */
    var WEST  = process.env.WEST,     
        NORTH = process.env.NORTH,
        EAST  = process.env.EAST,
        SOUTH = process.env.SOUTH,
        target= process.env.ITEM,
        title = process.env.ITEM,
        WIDTH = process.env.WIDTH;

/* D3js FUNCTION *************************************************** */
locationMap("body",800, target, title, WEST, NORTH, EAST, SOUTH); // <<======== defined in wikiatlas.js!

/* SVG PRINT ******************************************************* */
    var svgheader = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
    +'<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">';
    fs.writeFileSync('administrative_map_(wikiatlas_2014).svg', svgheader + window.d3.select("body").html());
    // console.log(window.d3.select("body").html());
 }
// END (D3JS) * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
);
```

But I then get that `ReferenceError: locationMap is not defined` error:

```
/data/yug/projects_active/make-modules/09_d3/location.node.js:30
locationMap("body",800, target, title, WEST, NORTH, EAST, SOUTH);
^
ReferenceError: locationMap is not defined
    at Object.done (/data/yug/projects_active/make-modules/09_d3/location.node.js:30:1)
    at /data/yug/projects_active/make-modules/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:270:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
make: *** [output] Error 8
```

**How should I load or frame `./js/wikiatlas.js` so I could use functions inside of it on my node.js / jsdom server script ?**

---

Seems related to : [In Node.js, how do I "include" functions from my other files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/) , [Nodejs script fails to print after d3.json()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663300/)

Comment: var wikiatlas = require('path/to/wikiatlas.js')

Comment: added `var wikiatlas = require('../js/wikiatlas.js')` , same error. Is there a specific syntax to call function within the library (such `locationMap()`) ?

Comment: adding `var wikiatlas = require('../js/wikiatlas.js')` , is not enough, you must also convert your script into nodejs module.export format if you take this road. Also, it take aout the advantage of working with single code for client & server sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you load your script into the window's context you also have to access it with the window, i.e. `window.locationMap`.

```
jsdom.env(
  "<html><body></body></html>",        // CREATE DOM HOOK:
  [ '../js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js', 
  '../js/d3.v3.min.js', 
  '../js/topojson.v1.min.js', 
  '../js/wikiatlas.js',             // <<======== my code (IMPORTANT !!)
  '../js/b64.js'],
```

then

```
window.locationMap("body",800, target, title, WEST, NORTH, EAST, SOUTH);
```

that's it.