# module.exports that include all functions in a single line

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, header

This is a follow-up question to [In Node.js, how do I "include" functions from my other files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files)

I would like to include an external js file that contains common functions for a node.js app.

From one of the answers in [In Node.js, how do I "include" functions from my other files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files), this can be done by

```
// tools.js
// ========
module.exports = {
  foo: function () {
    // whatever
  },
  bar: function () {
    // whatever
  }
};

var zemba = function () {
}
```

It is inconvenient to export each and every function. Is it possible to have a one-liner that exports all functions? Something that looks like this;

```
module.exports = 'all functions';
```

It is so much more convenient this way. It is also less buggy in case one forgets to export certain functions later.

If not a one-liner, are there simpler alternatives that make coding more convenient? I just want to include an external js file made up of common functions conveniently. Something like `include <stdio.h>` in C/C++.

Comment: No. This is not how Javascript works. The way you mention is the most efficient way.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can write all your function declarations first and then export them in an object:

```
function bar() {
   //bar
}

function foo() {
   //foo
}

module.exports = {
    foo, bar
};
```

There's no magical one-liner though, you need to explicitly export the functions you want to be public.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that is the best javascript can offer at the moment. It is one thing that makes me appreciate python.

Answer (score 26):

I have done something like the following:

```
var Exported = {
   someFunction: function() { },
   anotherFunction: function() { },
}

module.exports = Exported;
```

I require it in another file and I can access those functions

```
var Export = require('path/to/Exported');
Export.someFunction();
```

This is essentially just an object with functions in it, and then you export the object.

Comment: This solution is the least redundant.

Comment: However, this solution fails if you want one of your functions to call another one of your functions.  You might get around the problem by using a class.

Comment: @mareoraft How does it fail? To call anotherFunction in someFunction just do this.anotherFunction()

Answer (score 21):

A really old question but I just had to solve the same issue myself.
the solution I used was to define a Class inside the module to contain all my functions and simply export an instance of the class.

classes.js looks like this:

```
class TestClass
{
   Function1() {
        return "Function1";
    } 
    Function2() {
        return "Function2";
    }
}

module.exports = new TestClass();
```

app.js looks like this:

```
const TestClass = require("./classes");
console.log( TestClass.Function1);
```

just keep adding more functions to the class and they will be exported :)

Answer (score 16):

It is worth noting that in ES6, you can now export functions like this:

```
export function foo(){}
export function bar(){}
function zemba(){}
```

Simply write `export` before the functions you want to export. More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

Answer (score 14):

If you use ES6 you can do something like that:

```js
function bar() {
   //bar
}

function foo() {
   //foo
}

export default { bar, foo };
```

Answer (score 5):

```
const fs = require("fs")


var ExportAll = {

    deleteFile : function deleteFile(image,folder="uploads"){
    
        let imagePath = `public/${folder}/${image}`
    
        if (fs.existsSync(imagePath)){
            fs.unlinkSync(imagePath)
        }
    },


    checkFile : function checkFile(image,folder="uploads"){
    
        let imagePath = `public/${folder}/${image}`
    
        if (fs.existsSync(imagePath)){
            return true
        }
        else{
            return false
        }
    },
    

    rand : function(min=1,max=10) 
           {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min)
          }
}

module.exports = ExportAll
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to what you have tried and what isn't working to add some clarity to your problem

Answer (score 4):

Import everything from a type module file that has functions that are exported.

**Found here:**
https://javascript.info/import-export

**myfile.js**

```
export function myFunction()
{
// ................
}

export function myFunction2()
{
// ................
}
```

**myfile2.js** - import everything that is exported in the file

```
import * as myFunctions from './myfile.js';


// Usage 

    myFunctions.myFunction(); 
    myFunctions.myFunction2();
```