# Put functions declared in this format into single .js to be included in other files

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, header

I am using node.js. I would written several javascript functions to be shared across several files. I want to put these functions into a single file `tools.js`. Based on the answer in

[In Node.js, how do I "include" functions from my other files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files)

the functions need to be declared in this format (function expressions);

```
// tools.js
// ========
module.exports = {
  foo: function () {
    // whatever
  },
  bar: function () {
    // whatever
  }
};
```

However, the functions I have written are of this format;

```
function foo(a, b, c)
{
    //do whatever
}
```

I have several such functions. It is a chore to re-declare all of them in `tools.js` as function expressions. Is it possible to have `tools.js` use functions declared in my way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help from wonderful experts on hand, the simple answer to my own question is as follows;

```
// tools.js
// ========
module.exports = {
  foo: foo,
  bar: bar,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's even more work.

If you are on a kind of Unix and your format is *exactly* as described here you can use

```
sed -e 's/^\(function\)\([ ]\+\)\([a-zA-Z0-9]\+\)/\3: \1/g;s/^\}/\},/g'
```

to exchange the function declaration and put a comma after the last bracket. Also after the very last bracket but I don't think it's too much work to get rid of it by hand.

But as you are already playing with `node` you might use something in the line of the following (beware: works in-place!):

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile(YOUR_FILE, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  var result;
  // checks&balances omitted
  result = data.replace(/(function)([ ]+)([a-zA-Z-0-9]+)/g,"$3: $1");
  result = data.replace(/^}/g,"},");
  fs.writeFile(YOUR_FILE, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
     // checks&balances omitted
  });
});
```

(shouldn't it be utf-16?)