# Include javascript file in node.js script

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to include a javascript file in nodejs script to be able to test it with command "node script.js" ?

**//Edited** 
i have generated a browserify file using "browserify script.js > file.js", my nodejs script does just a "console.log()", i need now to test my file.js that i have generated with browserify using node.js not the browser, this is my code that i want to test from node.js script :

```
executeGeneratePNG= function(sBlob) {
var _generatePNG = function (){
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
// shim for using process in browser
var process = module.exports = {};
var queue = [];
var draining = false;
var currentQueue;
var queueIndex = -1;

function cleanUpNextTick() {
    draining = false;
    if (currentQueue.length) {
        queue = currentQueue.concat(queue);
    } else {
        queueIndex = -1;
    }
    if (queue.length) {
        drainQueue();
    }
}

function drainQueue() {
    if (draining) {
        return;
    }
    var timeout = setTimeout(cleanUpNextTick);
    draining = true;

    var len = queue.length;
    while(len) {
        currentQueue = queue;
        queue = [];
        while (++queueIndex < len) {
            if (currentQueue) {
                currentQueue[queueIndex].run();
            }
        }
        queueIndex = -1;
        len = queue.length;
    }
    currentQueue = null;
    draining = false;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}

process.nextTick = function (fun) {
    var args = new Array(arguments.length - 1);
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
        for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            args[i - 1] = arguments[i];
        }
    }
    queue.push(new Item(fun, args));
    if (queue.length === 1 && !draining) {
        setTimeout(drainQueue, 0);
    }
};

// v8 likes predictible objects
function Item(fun, array) {
    this.fun = fun;
    this.array = array;
}
Item.prototype.run = function () {
    this.fun.apply(null, this.array);
};
process.title = 'browser';
process.browser = true;
process.env = {};
process.argv = [];
process.version = ''; // empty string to avoid regexp issues
process.versions = {};

function noop() {}

process.on = noop;
process.addListener = noop;
process.once = noop;
process.off = noop;
process.removeListener = noop;
process.removeAllListeners = noop;
process.emit = noop;

process.binding = function (name) {
    throw new Error('process.binding is not supported');
};

process.cwd = function () { return '/' };
process.chdir = function (dir) {
    throw new Error('process.chdir is not supported');
};
process.umask = function() { return 0; };

},{}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
(function (process){
console.log("-------blob-------"+sBlob);
}).call(this,require('_process'))
},{"_process":1}]},{},[2]);

}
return {generatePNG :_generatePNG}
};
```

Comment: Share code of that file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Node.js, how do I "include" functions from my other files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files)

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript files should contain [ASM style modules](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html) and then can be included using `require`.

```
var myModule = require("./my-module.js");
```

Comment: @JitendraKhatri — That is what the first half of the first sentence of this answer says.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `require()`. Check out [Modules API](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) in Node.js.

```
var module = require("./script.js");
```