# How to bundle js files in none node environment?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm developing websites with several js files and I want to bundle these js files into one js file. I started looking at Webpack, but it requires node environment to run. In fact, all my js files are none-node style, and each one of them is independent. My development environment is not node, so I'm wondering how to make all my js files into one js file.

Comment: The information in this other question will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063407/node-js-requireing-other-files-without-needing-namespaces

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js 'require'ing other files without needing namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063407/node-js-requireing-other-files-without-needing-namespaces)

Answer (score 0):

Your js files do not need to be written as CommonJS modules ("node style") in order to bundle them with [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).

If you want you can use loaders like the [`imports-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/imports-loader) and [`exports-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/exports-loader) to make scripts not written as CommonJS modules accessible in a [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) context.

However, it sounds like you may not even need [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) for your use case.

I would recommend using a simple [gulp recipe](https://gulpjs.org/recipes/) to concatenate and minify your existing JavaScript files into a single file.

```
const concat = require('gulp-concat')
const gulp = require('gulp')
const rename = require('gulp-rename')
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify')

gulp.task('default', function () {
  // Find all the JavaScript files in the src directory.
  return gulp.src('src/*.js')
    // Concatenate them all together and name the resulting sciprt app.js.
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    // Minify the script to save space.
    .pipe(uglify())
    // Change the file extension.
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.js' }))
    // Output to the dist directory.
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
})
```