# Include existing js script in node.js

Tags: node.js

I understand node.js is modular, and js scripts are supposed to be included via [module.exports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5801971/1156245).  But let's say I don't care about best practice and just want to make everything (data objects, functions, etc) in a pre-existing javascript file e.g. `source.js` available to a node script `serve.js`.  Is there any way to achieve this?

This is a different to the question referenced above because that answer requires specifically formatted script using `module.exports`.

Comment: I'm not really informed on other methods, but I'd say you would probably end up fetching raw files with io, and using a form of eval. Honestly I'd try to find a way to convert these files in a node friendly manner, to avoid useless headaches

Comment: I'd be surprised is someone hadn't devised a method to achieve this.  It's ridiculous to have to manually edit every js source file to be compatible with `module.exports`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Node.js, how do I "include" functions from my other files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files)

Comment: If you check, I referenced that answer..