# Requiring other files in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to require another file within a node project I'm working on; this will be a command line tool. What I'm trying to do is create a formatted color output using the following file `format.js`:

```
modules.exports = {
    warning: function(input){
        say("\033[31m" + input)
    },

    info: function(input){
        say("\033[36m" + input)
    }
}
```

From there I want to create the colored output and put it into a file named `gen_email.js`. That file has these two functions in it:

```
function say(input){
    console.log(input)
}

function helpPage(){
    say('');
    format.info("test")
}
```

When I attempt to run this it outputs the following:

```
C:\Users\thomas_j_perkins\bin\javascript\node\email\lib\format.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { modules.exports = {
                                                              ^

ReferenceError: modules is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\thomas_j_perkins\bin\javascript\node\email\lib\for
mat.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\thomas_j_perkins\bin\javascript\node\email\gen_ema
il.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files) I am requiring the file the correct way. What am I doing wrong here, do I need to move the say function into the other file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
module.exports = {
warning: function(input){
    say("\033[31m" + input)
},

info: function(input){
    say("\033[36m" + input)
}
```

}

in the other file

```
const format = require("whatEverPathIsOn/format.js")
```

if the file is under the same path just

```
const format = require("./format.js")
```

Answer (score 0):

That should be `module`, not `modules`.

Comment: Will I still need to move the `say` function into the other file?

Comment: @13aal: You need to `require()` it

Comment: So require the function in the other file as well?