# NodeJS: How can I include some javascript code snippet without using require?

Tags: javascript, node.js, include, require, code-snippets

I wanted to include some js files without using require because it would link it to a variable, and i have some functions i would like to call directly. how can i do it ? is it bad practice ?

what i want to avoid is this:
let's say i have tool.js as follow:

```
function foo() {
    log.debug("foo");
}    
exports.foo = foo;
```

in app.js

```
var tool= require('tools.js');

tool.foo();
```

i would like to be able to call foo without creating a module for it as if it was define in app.js; like so

```
foo();
```

Comment: You can find the answer here (Please check the third answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files

Comment: you're link is show exactly what i wanted to avoid

Comment: Yes the third answer is right! sorry, i just checked the 2 first. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can require a file and use its functions without assigning it to a variable by using the global object.

file1.js

```
function logger(){
    console.log(arguments);
}

global.logger = logger;
```

file2.js

```
require('./file1');

logger('ABC');
```

This approach would get rid of variable scoping and would pollute the global namespace potentially leading to clashes with variable naming.

Comment: would this work if `global.logger = logger;` was missing in file1.js ? coz i saw someone doing it in a tutorial but it wasn"t working for me thanks for the warning by the way

Comment: It would not work, tested that first and the function was not available @Xsmael

Comment: This is very weird! now it works for me too, and i don't know why -_-

Answer (score 0):

You need to use global like this,

======= app.js ======

```
global.foo= require('tools.js'); // declare as global
foo(); // can be called from all files
```