# PHP auto_prepend_file alternative in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

In my NodeJS environment, I want to include a file that will contain some personal helper functions.

Basically I want the same behavior as PHP [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)

It should be included automatically both in projects as well as NodeJS CLI. Ideally it shouldn't require `require` statement. It should just create some global variables for functions that are available everywhere.

Comment: if u want to write some utility function in separate file then u have to import that file to make use of those function in nodejs, bcz nodejs  works require modules.

Comment: require once and use every where that can be possible

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you.. but do you mean the [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)?

they can be used so:

```
require_once('/path/to/file/helper_functions.php');
```

or

```
include('/path/to/file/helper_functions.php');
```

an example can be this:

```
$funcs_path = '/path/to/file/helper_functions.php'
if(file_exists ($funcs_path))
{
  require_once($funcs_path);
}
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: Ah sorry, it is my mistake. So do you want to include other files into nodeJS application.. try with this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files)