# Can't use non-anonymous method with socket.io, "listener" argument must be a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I searched for an answer to this (simple ?) question, yet, I can't find anything clear.

I'm a java developper trying to fit in the web market, but, as a OOP, many things infurate me.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("Client has connected! id = [" + socket.id + "]");

    socket.on('disconnect', onPlayerDisconnected(socket));
});

function onPlayerDisconnected(socket) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('player_disconnected', socket.id);

    console.log("Client has disconnected! id = [" + socket.id + "]");
}
```

Here's the stacktrace :

```
events.js:219
    throw new TypeError('"listener" argument must be a function');
    ^

TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function
```

If I use an anonymous function, it works like a charm. Problem is, if I react to an (increasing) number of events, the code won't be maintenable.

So, is there any way to break down the code to smaller functions ?

Bonus question : is it possible to event split the code in multiple .js files ?

Thanks a lot,
A node.js beginner.

Comment: For the includes from another file check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing in the result of the function `onPlayerDisconnected` (which appears to be `undefined` since nothing is returned) to the `socket.on('disconnect')` handler and not the actual function `onPlayerDisconnected` which is what it is looking for.

Change the below code which passes the result of `onPlayerDisconnected(socket)`

`socket.on('disconnect', onPlayerDisconnected(socket));`

to this code which just passes the actual function `onPlayerDisconnected`

`socket.on('disconnect', onPlayerDisconnected);`