# What is the Node.js equivalent of a PHP include?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for a simple solution for server side includes of regular HTML and CSS (for repeated components like headers, footers, navigation, etc) that doesn't require extensive frameworks.

Comment: `require('./my/file.js')` to reuse the same file though, you need to delete it from the require cache

Comment: PHP works very differently than Node/JavaScript. You should provide more details about what exactly you want. E.g. in PHP you can mix PHP code and plain text, and the PHP interpreter will just pass through the plain text. That's not how Node works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Node.js, how do I "include" functions from my other files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files)

Comment: Javascript is html-node manipulation tool, there is no native way for reading/including scripts from a hard drive. The most native you'll gonna get is via `script src`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the

`require()`

function. Check out the documentation for this and other Node.js things [here](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require)

If you want to use newer `import` statement, you may do so; it's not yet fully implemented in Node, but you can use it by using the `.mjs` extension on the file you need to import and then using the following command:

`node --experimental-modules someFile.mjs`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `require` to require multiple files. However, since node caches the files, you will need to delete them from the cache if you want to used an un-cached version of the file.

**index.js**

```
app.get('/path', (req, res) => {
  clear()
  let headers1 = require('/headers/a.js')
  let headers2 = require('/headers/b.js')
  res.set(headers1)
  res.set(headers2)
})

// Remove from require cache
function clear() {
  delete require.cache[require.resolve('/headers/a.js')]
  delete require.cache[require.resolve('/headers/b.js')]
}
```

**headers/a.js**

```
module.exports = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

**headers/b.js**

```
module.exports = {
  'Custom-Header': 'Brass Monkey'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In node js to include repetitive files like headers, footers etc. you will need a templating language such as ejs.

Using ejs here is a sample code snippet with the `include` tag

```
<%- include('./path/to/your/html/file') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you like require "view components". Exists multiple view engines for nodejs, for example [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) , or [ejs](http://ejs.co/). In this case, you use [include](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html)