# Nodejs access function from another file

Tags: node.js

I have a directory structure which looks somewhat like this (both folders have node_modules available)

```
- task1
     - src
          - shorten.js
- task2
     - src
          - api.js
          - server.js
```

In `shorten.js` I have two functions namely `shorten(url)` and `checkLink(url)` . At the end of the file, I have something as `module.exports = shorten`.

In the `api.js`, I have a line `const shorten = require("../../task1/src/shorten");`. If I simply call `shorten` with the parameter, it is having no problems, but the problem comes when I try to call `checkLink` in a similar way.

What should I do in order to be able to call `checkLink` inside api.js of task2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Node.js, how do I "include" functions from my other files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files)

Comment: @AramilRey I tried that by creating a var that holds a function, it did not work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to also export the checkLink function inside the shorten.js so you can then require it from the api.js...

Inside shorten.js change your module.exports to look like this:

```
module.exports = { shorten, checkLink }
```

Inside the api.js like this:

```
let myShortenFile = require ("../../task1/src/shorten")
myShortenFile.shorten() // to call shorten
myShortenFile.checkLink() // to call the checkLink
```

Hope this helps.

// UPDATE:

Since the OP has indicated he cannot export both functions and only wants to export 1 function and still have access to the second...

```
// shorten.js
const shorten = function(url, isCheckLink){
 if(isCheckLink){
  // Perform check link code
  return Result_of_check_link_function
 }
 else{
  return Result_of_shorten_function
 }
}

module.exports = shorten

// inside api.js
let myShortenFile = require ("../../task1/src/shorten")
myShortenFile.shorten('http://myurl.com') // to call shorten
myShortenFile.shorten('http://myurl.com', true) // pass true 
// as second argument to call the CheckLink function
```

Comment: Hey, I think I am only allowed to have shorten inside module.exports, else the test cases will fail. Is there no other way we can have it?

Comment: You could embed the checkLink function inside the exported shorten function and then setup argument that you can use to call the inside checkLink function

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are exporting only one function which is `module.exports = shorten`.

You need to export `checkLink(url)` as well same as `shorten` like below:

`module.exports = checkLink`

Another way to combine both exports like below:

```
module.exports = {
  shorten,
  checkLink
}
```

[Here](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) is one nice article about Exporting and Importing modules in nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply you can use module.exports

```
module.exports = {
    shorten: function(url) {
     //some process here
        return {
            success: true,
            data: url
        }
    },

    checkLink: function (any,values,here) {
        //some code
        return { value };
    }
}
```

In the request use as follow

```
let someShorten= require("./place/to/file");

someShorten.shorten('http://myurl.com');
```