# Accessing a functions from a js file thats in a public directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a JS file in a folder called `public`, which also has my CSS file in it. I'm trying to access a function from the JS file (`scripts.js`), but am having no luck. I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files) post (amongst others), but I am still getting an error of `Error: Cannot find module './scripts.js'`. If anyone can help me out, that would be great.

**app.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var request = require("request");
var scripts = require("/scripts.js");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

const apiUrl = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/"; 
const apiKey = "XXX";

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render("index");
});

app.post('/results', function(req, res){
    var lat = req.body.latitude;
    var long = req.body.longitude;
    request(apiUrl + apiKey + "/" + long + "," + lat, function(error, response, body){
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            var temperature = scripts.converter(data.currently.temperature)
            res.render("results", {data: data, temperature: temperature})
        } else {
            console.log(response.body);
        }
    });
});

app.get('/results', function(req, res){
    res.render("results");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server has started");
})
```

**scripts.js**

```
module.converter = function(cel) {
        var cel = (far - 32) * (5/9);
        return cel;
}

exports.data = module;
```

Comment: `require` doesn't access the files like a browser would (where `/scripts.js` would be the website root), but rather like your file explorer does. The right path is likely `./public/scripts.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to your module is wrong.
Try `var scripts = require("./public/scripts.js");` instead.

You are loading `/scripts.js`, which is a `scripts.js` file located at your computers *root*. To load a file in the current directory, you would do `./scripts.js`. In a directory above the current one, it would be `../scripts.js`.

If the file is in a directory below the current directory, like in your case, it would be './directoryname/scripts.js'. `directoryname` being `public` in your case