# exporting from yet-another-webpack-es6-starterkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm using 'yet-another-webpack-es6-starterkit' as my build kit. Unmodified, no changed package.json settings.

The code works well on its own but I need to export a function in the main index.js file so the function can be used by other js files in a node environment.

This is the example code I used for how to export:
[In Node.js, how do I "include" functions from my other files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files)

I created a test function called 'test' in the index.js.

```
module.exports = {
test: function () {
    var r = 42;
    return r;
}
```

};

But the external file cannot find the function. It doesn't seem to be visible from outside the js file.

Comment: How do you include this function ? Maybe your code got cyclic dependencies