# Import module from npm to javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to import `showdown` module in my `home.js` file.

The GitHub installation guide tells me to run `npm install showdown` and presents a simple example of using the module, as such:

```
var converter = new showdown.Converter(),
    text      = '# hello, markdown!',
    html      = converter.makeHtml(text);
```

I have installed the module using that command, but now I m not sure how to use this module inside my `home.js` situated under `app/static/js` path. I tried using `require` but it s not a solution since

> it does not exist in the browser/client-side JavaScript.

**Project Tree**

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── routes.py
│   └── static
│       ├── js
│       │   └── home.js
│       └── styles
│           ├── main.css
│           └── normalize.css
├── config.py
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── run.py
└── node_modules
```

**Javascript file** `home.js`

```
const textEditor = document.querySelector('.text-editor')
const preview = document.querySelector('.preview')
var converter = new showdown.Converter() // <- error fires here

console.log('text-editor', textEditor)
console.log('preview', preview)

textEditor.addEventListener('keyup', event=>{
    const {value} = event.target;

    const html = converter.makeHtml(value)

    preview.innerHtml = html
});
```

Question: How do I import this `showdown` inside my `index.js` so that I can be able to use every function of the module?

Comment: Looking at [the documentation](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) it lists `npm install showdown` under "npm (server-side)". Why are you following **that** section of the instructions when you are writing **client-side** JavaScript?!

Comment: You probably want to use webpack or similar to bundle everything together for the browser, but I'm out-of-date (there may be better tools, or browser support I don't know about)

Comment: @Quentin should I use `bower install showdown` instead? Please let me know the difference whenever you can.

Comment: @Rup someone told me sth about bundling, I ll research more on that then.

Comment: @newbie99 — Are you using bower as a package manager already? If so, yes. Otherwise, no.

Comment: I was following someone s tutorial on `showdown` and he did the same thing. He first did `npm install showdown` then copied the `node_modules/showdown/dist/showdown.js` into his project using it without a problem. But for me, didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Browserify` for this.
It allows you to use `require()` for requiring node_modules.

Here are the steps in which you can use the `showdown` npm package in your project.

1. Install `browserify` globally using: `npm install -g browserify`
2. Use `require()` to include your npm modules in your project.

   > `const showdown = require('showdown');`
3. Prepare a bundle for accessing require() function in your `home.js` usnig browserify:

   > `browserify js/home.js > bundle.js`
4. Include the `bundle.js` file created in your code using the `script` tag.

   > `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`

Here are some resources that explain how to use `browserify` in more detail:

1. https://medium.com/jeremy-keeshin/hello-world-for-javascript-with-npm-modules-in-the-browser-6020f82d1072
2. https://github.com/browserify/browserify#usage

Additionally, [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-browserify) article also explains well how to choose the tool for compiling your front-end applications based on your requirements. And it contains detailed information about how to use `browserify`

Comment: Do I need to `npm install exorcist` as well?

Comment: No you dont need to install exorcist. It is an optional step required to separate `source-map` files. I have also updated the command in my answer.

Comment: Where should I write the 2nd step with `const showdown=require('showdown')`. In my `main.js` file doesn't work. I get `require` is not defined

Comment: @newbie99 more info regarding `what does not work` is needed, and `be self-motivated`. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files) is info about `require`.