# Include files in node.js directly

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, include

I know this questions sounds like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files) but it isn't.
This questions shows how to include a file that then stores all of its members in an own namespace. But is there a way to include the file, so that the members are in the default namespace?

So I want something like this,

```
include("abc.js");

testFunc(1, 2, 3);
```

where `testFunc` is declared in abc.js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: Not exactly, but it doesn't matter, since an answer has been found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a common namespace in `node.js` that all loaded files has access to, `global`

In `abc.js`:

```js
global.testFunc = () => 'bar';
```

so below will work

```js
require('./abc');

testFunc(1, 2, 3);
```

However this is not really advised to be used for performance purposes, except for config values for example

Comment: I couldn't do it, because I had to wait one minute for what ever reason

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware about this timeout

Answer (score 1):

First nodejs does not know `include`, you should use `require` or `import`

If you have a module (`testModule`):

```
module.exports = {
    testFunc: (...args) => {/* ... */}
}
```

You should be able to import `testFunc` into the current 'namespace' using

```
const {testFunc} = require("./testModule.js");
```