# Did node require change?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I previously included other js files into my node projects using `require` as seen on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63313365/include-files-in-node-js-directly).
But for some reason this no longer works, did Node change or am I missing some mistake?

This is my code:

main.js:

```
require("./test");

console.log(x);
```

test.js:

```
var x = 3;
```

Running this code results in this error message:

```
main.js:3
console.log(x);
            ^

ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

Comment: Your module does not export x / does not add x to the global object

Comment: You should read up about exports and require.. and also this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export)

Comment: @GoldenretriverYT but it worked previously

Comment: @user11914177 no - you probably did put them in global or exported them when "it worked"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at an other project I found what I wanted:

test.js:

```
global.x = 3;
```

main.js:

```
require("./test");

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to add this -
test.js:

```
const x = 3;
module.exports = x;
```

main.js:

```
const x = require('./test.js');
console.log(x);
```

And documentation:
https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use variable declare in the required file without exporting variables.

[More document about export](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-module-exports)

test.js:

```js
var x = 3;

module.exports.x = x;
```

main.js:

```js
var test = require("./test");

console.log(test.x);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to export var from `test.js`

```
export var x = 3;
```

after that import into `main.js`

```
var { x } = require("./test");
console.log(x);
```