# MongoDB Cannot find module '/booksSchema' on Mac Catalina

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have created 3 files MongoDBConnect.js, booksSchema.js, Server.js and am running visualstudio.

When I run node server.js  I get "Cannot find module '/booksSchema'" error.
booksSchema is in the same directory as all other files.

MongoDBConnect.js

> mongoose= require('mongoose')

> const MONG_URI= 'mongodb://localhost:27017/BooksData'
> mongoose.connect(MONG_URI,{useUnifiedTopology:true,useNewUrlParser:true, useFindAndModify:false })
> const db= mongoose.connection;
> db.on('error',function(err){ 
> console.log('Error occured'+err)
> })
> db.once('connected',function(){
> console.log('connection is successful to'+ MONG_URI)
> })
>
> module.exports=db

booksSchema.js

> let mongoose= require('mongoose')
> const BookScheme= new mongoose.Schema({
> booktitle:{
> type:String,
> required:true 
> },
> PubYear:Number, 
> author:String, 
> Topic:String, 
> formate:String
> })
>
> module.exports= mongoose.model('bookmodel',BookScheme,'BookCollection2')

I won't put the whole Server.js code here but here are the first lines

> var express = require("express")
> let Books = require('/booksSchema')
> let mongodbConnected = ('/MongoDBConnect')
> const cors = require('cors');

I keep getting throw err;

Error: Cannot find module '/booksSchema'

Why can't it see the booksSchema?  They are all in the same directory. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need `./booksSchema`, with a dot at the start. The first result for a search for "node require own files": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files

Comment: Wow, such a quick response.  Thank you so much.  You are a star.  I knew it would be something small that a newbie would have missed.  Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so this isn't left unanswered, someone in the comments pointed out that I had missed the dot before my booksSchema path so it should have been './booksSchema' instead of '/booksSchema'.