# Issues importing helper functions into cucumber-js step definitions

Tags: javascript, cucumber, node-modules, commonjs, cucumberjs

Node version: **16.13.2**

Cucumber-js version: **7.3.2**

**Problem:**
I cannot import into my step definitions, a helper function exported from another file.
I want to import the function, `hex2rgb()` located in *test/features/support/helpers.js*
into one of my step definitions, located in *test/features/step_definitions/steps.js*.   The function takes a string argument, converts it to an rgb value and returns it.

The project structure at */home/jimjamz/dev/colours*:

```
├── package.json
└── test
    ├── features
    │   ├── colours.feature
    │   ├── step_definitions
    │   │   └── steps.js
    │   └── support
    │       ├── helpers.js
    │       └── support.js
```

Tests are run by executing `./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js test`.

**Question:** What is the most appropriate way to export a helper function from another file, and import it into my [cucumber-js](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/esm.md) step definitions?

There are a variety of ways I have configured the export and import of the helper function, all resulting in varying errors.

**1) ECMAScript**

*helpers.js*:

```
export function hex2rgb(in_hex) {
...
```

*steps.js*:

```
import { hex2rgb } from '../support/helpers.js';

Then('I should see the colour {string}', async function (colour) {
  rgb_colour = hex2rgb(colour);
}
```

or
*steps.js*:

```
const { hex2rgb } = require('../support/helpers');
```

*Result:*

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' // this error can be resolved by renaming the helper file to helpers.mjs
```

**2) CommonJS**

*helpers.js*:

```
exports = function hex2rgb(in_hex)
```

*steps.js*:

```
let helpers = require('../support/helpers');


Then('I should see the colour {string}', async function (colour) {
  rgb_colour = helpers.hex2rgb(colour);
}
```

*Result*:

```
TypeError: helpers.hex2rgb is not a function
```

**3) NodeJS Modules**

Added `"type": "module",` to *package.json* at project root level (otherwise, `ReferenceError: modules is not defined`).

*helpers.js*:

```
modules.export = function hex2rgb(in_hex)
```

*steps.js*:

```
const { hex2rgb } = require('../support/helpers');
```

*Result*:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/jimjamz/dev/colours/test/features/step_definitions/steps.js from /home/jimjamz/dev/colours/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/lib/cli/index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of steps.js in /home/jimjamz/dev/colours/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/lib/cli/index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at /home/jimjamz/dev/colours/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/lib/cli/index.js:122:17

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/jimjamz/dev/colours/test/features/support/helpers.js from /home/jimjamz/dev/colours/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/lib/cli/index.js not supported.
helpers.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename helpers.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in /home/jimjamz/dev/colours/package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).
    at /home/jimjamz/dev/colours/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/lib/cli/index.js:122:17
```

**4) Renaming the helpers file to .mjs or .cjs**
I've tried several variations of the above, but with a renamed helpers function file with the *.mjs* and *.cjs* file extensions.

These result in the same errors as above, `[ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() not supported.  Instead change the require to a dynamic import()`, which when done, results in the `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` error.  Using `""type": "module` results in the same `[ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]` as above.  Switching to `"type": "commonjs"` and using .cjs as the file extension, results in the `TypeError: hex2rgb is not a function` when importing with `require()` and `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` when switching to use `import`.

Resources I used:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5801971/6692696
- https://medium.com/computed-comparisons/commonjs-vs-amd-vs-requirejs-vs-es6-modules-2e814b114a0b
- https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-import-and-export-functions-in-javascript/
- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/1304
- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/pull/1589
- https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your examples are pretty close. I think this one matches your intent best, if you stick with CommonJS:

```js
// helpers.js
function hex2rgb(in_hex) {...}

module.exports = {
  hex2rgb
}
```

```js
// steps.js
const { hex2rgb } = require('../support/helpers.js')
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help @David Goss and the discussions over this.  The explanations were very much appreciated.  I realised some of my mistakes in my import / export examples and not to use out-of-date guides.  Small world! :)