# Call one file from another in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope

I know this problem has been generally discussed already, but my specific situation is different. I need to call a function in one file from another file, but I can't change code from another file. here is an example:

file1.js:
`console.log(function1(param1, param2));`

file2.js:
`function1(param1, param2) { return param1 + param2; }`

I can change anything I want about file1, but I cannot change any of the code in file2.

I looked this up fairly extensively before making this post and I found that what I just described is possible in JavaScript because of global scope. But in practice, trying to run file2.js results in "ReferenceError: function1 is not defined" I am experienced in Java but not JavaScript so I don't know how to solve this or if it is solvable. I am using Github Codespaces with VSCode to edit files.

Edit: I'm terribly sorry about this but I only noticed it after the first answers. I meant that I can change anything about file 2, but not file 1. I am currently using this to output to the terminal, so I would assume Node.js

Comment: How are you importing between files? Is this in browser or in Node? Can you use `require` or `import`?

Comment: "would assume Node.js" you don't know? That seems odd to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Node.js, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5809968/20861351) should fix your issue if added to the top of file1. Otherwise, if you are using HTML, you can simply add file2's script tag above file1's like so:

```
<script src="file2.js"></script>
<script src="file1.js"></script>
```