# What do "module.exports" and "exports.methods" mean in NodeJS / Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module, export

Looking at a random [source file](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js) of the `express` framework for `NodeJS`, there are two lines of the code that I do not understand (these lines of code are typical of almost all NodeJS files).

```
/**
 * Expose `Router` constructor.
 */

exports = module.exports = Router;
```

and

```
/**
 * Expose HTTP methods.
 */

var methods = exports.methods = require('./methods');
```

I understand that the *first piece of code* **allows the rest of the functions in the file to be exposed to the NodeJS app**, but I don't understand exactly **how it works**, or what the code in the line means.

> What do `exports` and `module.exports` actually mean?

I believe the 2nd piece of code allows the functions in the file to access `methods`, but again, how exactly does it do this.

Basically, what are these magic words: **`module`** and **`exports`**?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

To be more specific:

`module` is the global scope variable inside a file.

So if you call `require("foo")` then :

```
// foo.js
console.log(this === module); // true
```

It acts in the same way that `window` acts in the browser.

There is also another global object called `global` which you can write and read from in any file you want, but that involves mutating global scope and this is **EVIL**

`exports` is a variable that lives on `module.exports`. It's basically what you *export* when a file is required.

```
// foo.js
module.exports = 42;

// main.js
console.log(require("foo") === 42); // true
```

There is a minor problem with `exports` on it's own. The _global scope context+ and `module` are **not** the same. (In the browser the global scope context and `window` are the same).

```
// foo.js
var exports = {}; // creates a new local variable called exports, and conflicts with

// living on module.exports
exports = {}; // does the same as above
module.exports = {}; // just works because its the "correct" exports

// bar.js
exports.foo = 42; // this does not create a new exports variable so it just works
```

[Read more about exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-nodejs-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it)

Comment: Any chance you can explain why the exports = module.exports = Router; construct is used?

Comment: That's unfortunate because most of the source I've seen so far (which I'll admit is pretty limited) uses it including connect.js

Comment: @ShaneCourtrille he appears to want to set `module.exports` to `Router` and then wants to add properties to `exports` instead of `Router` so that's why he does all three. I would call that a silly coding style since he could just add properties to `Router` directly instead.

Comment: I can't believe I've been using Node.JS for this long now and have been thinking the global object was `process` rather than `module`. +1

Comment: @ShaneCourtrille this answer explains why in more detail:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17944431/404699

Comment: I'm seeing different behavior to your `console.log(this === module); // true`? In my tests, Node.js / webpack / browserify set `this` inside require-ed module to be the same as `exports` rather than `module`.

Answer (score 34):

To expand on Raynos's answer...

`exports` is basically an **alias** for `module.exports` - I recommend just not using it.  You can **expose methods and properties from a module by setting them on `module.exports`**, as follows:

```
//file 'module1.js'
module.exports.foo = function () { return 'bar' }
module.exports.baz = 5
```

Then you get access to it in your code:

```
var module1 = require('module1')
console.log(module1.foo())
console.log(module1.baz)
```

You can also **override** `module.exports` entirely to simply provide a single object upon require:

```
//glorp.js
module.exports = function () {
  this.foo = function () { return 'bar' }
  this.baz = 5
  return this // need to return `this` object here
}
```

Now you've got a nice prototype:

```
var g1 = new require('glorp')()
console.log(g1.foo())
console.log(g1.baz)
```

There are myriad other ways to play with `module.exports` and `require`.  Just remember, `require('foo')` **always returns the same instance** even if you call it multiple times.

## Note

For the following to work,

```
var g1 = new require('glorp')()
console.log(g1.foo())
console.log(g1.baz)
```

`this` has to be returned in the function that is assigned to `module.exports`. Otherwise, you'll get a `TypeError`:

```
console.log(g1.foo())
          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined
```

Answer (score 15):

You can find the best answer in node.js source code.
If someone is requiring your js module, 
your script turns into a function by node as follows (see src/node.js).

```
// require function does this..
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
    ... your javascript contents...
});
```

Node will wrap your script. Then above script will be executed as follows:

```
//module.js
var args = [self.exports, require, self, filename, dirname];
return compiledWrapper.apply(self.exports, args);
```

So in your script,

```
exports is just module.exports.
```

In your script, you can add something to this exports object (functions..).
require function will return this object. This is node.js's module system (commonJS specification).

But be careful not to modify module.exports. Otherwise your current exports will be meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

module is an object that represents what that particular source file would like to publicly expose. Instead of having something akin to header files in the c/c++ world, you describe what the module *exports* by defining this object. the node runtime then uses this object to determine what about your module is 'public.'

its a similar concept to exporting functions from a dll in the compiled world. you have to define explicitly what functions can be accessed by the outside world. this helps with encapsulation and lets your organize your libraries in a clean way.

Answer (score 0):

Module's code is wrapped in **module.exports** (The module, maybe composed by other module).
There are many ways to build a module, but this is one very common (and my personal favorite).

```
// Dependencies
// const module = require('module');

// Module object
var foo = {}

// Internal property
foo._a = 'a';

// "Public" property
foo.b = 'b';

// Method
foo.fu = function() { return 'fu' };

// Export
module.exports = foo;
```