# module.exports vs exports in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

I've found the following contract in a Node.js module:

```
module.exports = exports = nano = function database_module(cfg) {...}
```

I wonder what's the difference between `module.exports` and `exports` and why both are used here.

Comment: For posterity: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#module.exports

Comment: Updated 'for posterity' link: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports

Comment: It's all about references. Think of exports like a local variable object pointing to module.exports. If you overrite the value of exports, then you lose the reference to module.exports, and module.exports is what you expose as a public interface.

Comment: **Quick Summary:** both `exports` and `module.exports` point to the same object, unless you reassign one. And in the end `module.exports` is returned. So if you reassigned `exports` to a function then dont expect a function since it isn't going to be returned. However if you had assigned function like this `exports.func = function...` then resulting thing would have func property with function as a value. Because you added the property to the object that `exports` was pointing to ..

Comment: Can't understand why provide both `module.exports` and `exports`. Why not just provide `module.exports` to avoid such confusion?

Comment: @Neal, hacksparrow - "if you want your module to be of a specific object type, use module.exports; if you want your module to be a typical module instance, use exports." huh, what, why?.

Comment: Here is my 2 minute article on this topic (written in Node v6 and ES2015): https://medium.com/@lazlojuly/node-js-module-exports-vs-exports-ec7e254d63ac

Comment: Well, I have read every single reply here, and I still have no clue what the difference between the two is, when and how to use one vs. the other, or why there are two.

Comment: `module.exports` is not a function... Why is that?

Comment: @JohnLittle check out my new answer re: why use both https://stackoverflow.com/a/50162465/4722345

Comment: @TarranJones I've added my own words for clarity ([]): 
If you want your module to be of a specific object type [(such as a function/string/array)], use module.exports; 
if you want your module to be a typical module instance, [you should] use exports [, exclusively, to be concise].

See my answer for examples etc. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50162465/4722345

Comment: Updated link to hacksparrow post: https://www.hacksparrow.com/nodejs/exports-vs-module-exports.html

Comment: Great resource (as the first link is dead) : https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Answer (score 462, accepted):

Setting `module.exports` allows the `database_module` function to be called like a function when `required`.  Simply setting `exports` wouldn't allow the function to be
exported because node exports the object `module.exports` references.  The following code wouldn't allow the user to call the function.

#### module.js

**The following won't work.**

```
exports = nano = function database_module(cfg) {return;}
```

**The following will work if `module.exports` is set.**

```
module.exports = exports = nano = function database_module(cfg) {return;}
```

**console**

```
var func = require('./module.js');
// the following line will **work** with module.exports
func();
```

Basically **node.js** doesn't export the object that `exports` currently references, but exports the properties of what `exports` originally references.  Although **Node.js** does export the object `module.exports` references, allowing you to call it like a function.

---

#### 2nd least important reason

They set both `module.exports` and `exports` to ensure `exports` isn't referencing the prior exported object.  By setting both you use `exports` as a shorthand and avoid potential bugs later on down the road.

Using `exports.prop = true`  instead of `module.exports.prop = true` saves characters and avoids confusion.

Comment: @ajostergaard: It just happens to be the name of the [library](https://github.com/dscape/nano/blob/master/nano.js) the OP's example was taken from.  In the module, it allows the author to write things like `nano.version = '3.3'` instead of `module.exports.version = '3.3'`, which reads a little more clearly.  (Note that `nano` is a local variable, [declared a little before the module exports are set](https://github.com/dscape/nano/blob/3.3.7/nano.js#L17-45).)

Comment: @lime - thanks - I'm glad it's largely irrelevant because if it wasn't it would mean I'd completely misunderstood everything. :-| :)

Comment: Hey Lime, this is a pretty old answer but I hope you can clarify something. If I were to set `module.exports` but *not* `exports`, would my code still work? Thanks for any help!

Comment: @Asad Yes the function will export properly provided you set `module.exports`

Comment: I have no idea why they don't apply `set` `Proxy` for `exports`.

Answer (score 656):

Even though the question has been answered and accepted long ago, I just want to share my 2 cents.

You can imagine that at the very beginning of your file there is something like (just for explanation):

```
var module = new Module(...);
var exports = module.exports;
```

[image]

So whatever you do just keep in mind that `module.exports` and NOT `exports` will be returned from your module when you're requiring that module from somewhere else.

So when you do something like:

```
exports.a = function() {
    console.log("a");
}
exports.b = function() {
    console.log("b");
}
```

You are adding 2 functions `a` and `b` to the object to which `module.exports` points, so the `typeof` the returning result will be an `object` : `{ a: [Function], b: [Function] }`

Of course, this is the same result you will get if you are using `module.exports` in this example instead of `exports`.

This is the case where you want your `module.exports` to behave like a container of exported values. Whereas, if you only want to export a constructor function then there is something you should know about using `module.exports` or `exports`. Recall that `module.exports` will be returned when you require something, not `exports`.

```
module.exports = function Something() {
    console.log('bla bla');
}
```

Now `typeof` returning result is `'function'` and you can require it and immediately invoke it like:

 `var x = require('./file1.js')();` because you overwrite the returning result to be a function.

However, using `exports` you can't use something like:

```
exports = function Something() {
    console.log('bla bla');
}
var x = require('./file1.js')(); //Error: require is not a function
```

Because with `exports`, the reference **no longer points** to the object where `module.exports` points, so there is not a relationship between `exports` and `module.exports` anymore. In this case `module.exports` still points to the empty object `{}` which will be returned.

The accepted answer from another topic should also help:
[Does JavaScript pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference)

Comment: Nice explanation but I still don't understand how you can completely omit `module.exports` from a module, for example in this `npm` package: https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/blob/master/lib/consolidate.js

Comment: @Imray the explanation is here: [Does JavaScript pass by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference)

`exports.a = function(){}; works,


exports = function(){} doesn't work`

Comment: oooo finally this answer explains it. Basically export refers to an object to which you can add properties but if you **reassign** it to function then you are no long attach a property to that original object. Now export refer to function while module.exports is still pointing to that object and since it's what's returned. You can say export has been basically garbage collected.

Comment: So then, what's the point of using `exports`? Why not just always use `module.exports` if it's just a variable reassignment? Seems confusing to me.

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung
It is less cumbersome to write `exports.something` instead of `module.exports.something`

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung by adding properties to `exports` you are effectively ensuring that you are returning a "typical" module export *object*. In contrast, by using `module.exports` you can return any value you want (primitive, array, function) and not just an object (which is the format most people expect). So `module.exports` offers more power but can also be used to have your module export atypical values (like a primitive). In contrast `exports` is more limiting but safer (so long as you simply add properties to it and don't reassign it).

Comment: For me, this was the answer that clicked. Thumbs up for the concise explanation. I recommend everyone to create a node project and constantly log the objects `exports` and `module.exports` to see its behavior.

Comment: Webpack5 introduces some changes in library behaviour related to these export settings:  https://hinty.io/devforth/fix-webpack-imported-module-is-not-a-function-for-webpack5/

Answer (score 218):

Basically the answer lies in what really happens when a module is required via `require` statement. Assuming this is the first time the module is being required.

For example:

```
var x = require('file1.js');
```

contents of file1.js:

```
module.exports = '123';
```

When the above statement is executed, a `Module` object is created. Its constructor function is:

```
function Module(id, parent) {
    this.id = id;
    this.exports = {};
    this.parent = parent;
    if (parent && parent.children) {
        parent.children.push(this);
    }

    this.filename = null;
    this.loaded = false;
    this.children = [];
}
```

As you see each module object has a property with name `exports`. This is what is eventually returned as part of `require`.

Next step of require is to wrap the contents of file1.js into an anonymous function like below:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 
    //contents from file1.js
    module.exports = '123;
});
```

And this anonymous function is invoked the following way, `module` here refers to the `Module` Object created earlier.

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 
    //contents from file1.js
    module.exports = '123;
}) (module.exports,require, module, "path_to_file1.js","directory of the file1.js");
```

As we can see inside the function, `exports` formal argument refers to `module.exports`. In essence it's a convenience provided to the module programmer.

However this convenience need to be exercised with care. In any case if trying to assign a new object to exports ensure we do it this way.

```
exports = module.exports = {};
```

If we do it following way *wrong way*, `module.exports` will still be pointing to the object created as part of module instance.

```
exports = {};
```

As as result adding anything to the above exports object will have no effect to module.exports object and nothing will be exported or returned as part of require.

Comment: Lost me here `exports = module.exports = {};`

Comment: I think this should be the best answer, it explains why `func()` fails in @William's answer!

Comment: I don't see any advantage to add  `exports = module.exports = app;` at the last line of the code. It seems like the `module.exports` will get exported and we will never use `exports`, because again it's at the last line of the code. So, why don't we just simply add `module.exports = app;`

Answer (score 108):

Initially,`module.exports=exports` , and the `require` function returns the object `module.exports` refers to.

if we **add property** to the object, say `exports.a=1`, then module.exports and exports **still** refer to the same object. So if we call require and assign the module to a variable, then the variable has a property a and its value is 1;

But if we **override** one of them, for example, `exports=function(){}`, then they are **different** now: exports refers to a new object and module.exports refer to the original object. And if we require the file, it will not return the new object, since module.exports is not refer to the new object.

For me, i will keep adding new property, or override both of them to a new object. Just override one is not right. And keep in mind that `module.exports` is the real boss.

Comment: Yeah, this is actually the real answer. It's concise and clear. Others may be right but full of fancy terms and not focus exactly on the answer for this question.

Answer (score 71):

`exports` and `module.exports` are the same unless you reassign `exports` within your module.

The easiest way to think about it, is to think that this line is implicitly at the top of every module.

```
var exports = module.exports = {};
```

If, within your module, you reassign `exports`, then you reassign it within your module and it no longer equals `module.exports`. This is why, if you want to export a function, you must do:

```
module.exports = function() { ... }
```

If you simply assigned your `function() { ... }` to `exports`, you would be reassigning `exports` to no longer point to `module.exports`.

If you don't want to refer to your function by `module.exports` every time, you can do:

```
module.exports = exports = function() { ... }
```

Notice that `module.exports` is the left most argument.

Attaching properties to `exports` is not the same since you are not reassigning it. That is why this works

```
exports.foo = function() { ... }
```

Answer (score 37):

### JavaScript passes objects by copy of a reference

It's a subtle difference to do with the way objects are passed by reference in JavaScript.

`exports` and `module.exports` both point to the same object. `exports` is a variable and `module.exports` is an attribute of the module object.

Say I write something like this:

```
exports = {a:1};
module.exports = {b:12};
```

`exports` and `module.exports` now point to different objects. Modifying exports no longer modifies module.exports.

When the import function inspects `module.exports` it gets `{b:12}`

Comment: "JavaScript passes by reference" – **No.**

Comment: Best answer I read till here. But one question: if `const b = require()` gets me the `{b:12}`, how can I import it to get `{a:1}`?

Answer (score 14):

I just make some test, it turns out that, inside nodejs's module code, it should something like this:

```
var module.exports = {};
var exports = module.exports;
```

so:

## 1:

```
exports = function(){}; // this will not work! as it make the exports to some other pointer
module.exports = function(){}; // it works! cause finally nodejs make the module.exports to export.
```

## 2:

```
exports.abc = function(){}; // works!
exports.efg = function(){}; // works!
```

## 3: but, while in this case

```
module.exports = function(){}; // from now on we have to using module.exports to attach more stuff to exports.
module.exports.a = 'value a'; // works
exports.b = 'value b'; // the b will nerver be seen cause of the first line of code we have do it before (or later)
```

Comment: Lyman, so `module.exports` is sort of the 'real-deal' that node goes off of but at some point you'll need to add all your `exports` to `module.exports` unless you're using a `exports.namespace` (case 2 above), which in that case seems to be like Node ran a `extends(module.exports, exports);` adding all 'namespaces' of `exports` to the `module.exports` object? In other words, if you're using `exports` then you probably want to be setting properties on it?

Answer (score 13):

Here is a good description written about node modules in **node.js in action** book from **Manning** publication.
What ultimately gets exported in your application is *module.exports.
 exports* is set
up simply as a global reference to *module.exports* , which initially is defined as an
empty object that you can add properties to. So *exports.myFunc* is just shorthand
for *module.exports.myFunc*.
As a result, if *exports* is set to anything else, it breaks the **reference** between
*module.exports* and *exports* . Because *module.exports* is what really gets
exported, *exports* will no longer work as expected—it doesn’t reference *module
.exports* anymore. If you want to maintain that link, you can make *module.exports*
reference *exports*  again as follows:

```
module.exports = exports = db;
```

Answer (score 13):

To understand the differences, you have to first understand what Node.js does to every module during runtime. Node.js creates a wrapper function for every module:

```js
 (function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {

 })()
```

Notice the first param `exports` is an empty object, and the third param `module` is an object with many properties, and one of the properties is named `exports`. This is what `exports` comes from and what `module.exports` comes from. The former one is a variable object, and the latter one is a property of `module` object.

Within the module, Node.js automatically does this thing at the beginning: `module.exports = exports`, and **ultimately returns `module.exports`.**

So you can see that if you reassign some value to `exports`, it won't have any effect to `module.exports`. (Simply because `exports` points to another new object, but `module.exports` still holds the old `exports`)

```js
let exports = {};
const module = {};
module.exports = exports;

exports = { a: 1 }
console.log(module.exports) // {}
```

But if you updates properties of `exports`, it will surely have effect on `module.exports`. Because they both point to the same object.

```js
let exports = {};
const module = {};
module.exports = exports;

exports.a = 1;
module.exports.b = 2;
console.log(module.exports) // { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

Also notice that if you reassign another value to `module.exports`, then it seems meaningless for `exports` updates. Every updates on `exports` is ignored because `module.exports` points to another object.

```js
let exports = {};
const module = {};
module.exports = exports;

exports.a = 1;
module.exports = {
  hello: () => console.log('hello')
}
console.log(module.exports) // { hello: () => console.log('hello')}
```

Answer (score 9):

I went through some tests and I think this may shed some light on the subject...

**`app.js`:**

```
var ...
  , routes = require('./routes')
  ...;
...
console.log('@routes', routes);
...
```

**versions of `/routes/index.js`:**

```
exports = function fn(){}; // outputs "@routes {}"

exports.fn = function fn(){};  // outputs "@routes { fn: [Function: fn] }"

module.exports = function fn(){};  // outputs "@routes function fn(){}"

module.exports.fn = function fn(){};  // outputs "@routes { fn: [Function: fn] }"
```

I even added new files:

**`./routes/index.js`:**

```
module.exports = require('./not-index.js');
module.exports = require('./user.js');
```

**`./routes/not-index.js`:**

```
exports = function fn(){};
```

**`./routes/user.js`:**

```
exports = function user(){};
```

We get the output "@routes {}"

---

**`./routes/index.js`:**

```
module.exports.fn = require('./not-index.js');
module.exports.user = require('./user.js');
```

**`./routes/not-index.js`:**

```
exports = function fn(){};
```

**`./routes/user.js`:**

```
exports = function user(){};
```

We get the output "@routes { fn: {}, user: {} }"

---

**`./routes/index.js`:**

```
module.exports.fn = require('./not-index.js');
module.exports.user = require('./user.js');
```

**`./routes/not-index.js`:**

```
exports.fn = function fn(){};
```

**`./routes/user.js`:**

```
exports.user = function user(){};
```

We get the output "@routes { user: [Function: user] }"
If we change `user.js` to `{ ThisLoadedLast: [Function: ThisLoadedLast] }`, we get the output "@routes { ThisLoadedLast: [Function: ThisLoadedLast] }".

---

But if we modify `./routes/index.js`...

**`./routes/index.js`:**

```
module.exports.fn = require('./not-index.js');
module.exports.ThisLoadedLast = require('./user.js');
```

**`./routes/not-index.js`:**

```
exports.fn = function fn(){};
```

**`./routes/user.js`:**

```
exports.ThisLoadedLast = function ThisLoadedLast(){};
```

... we get "@routes { fn: { fn: [Function: fn] }, ThisLoadedLast: { ThisLoadedLast: [Function: ThisLoadedLast] } }"

So I would suggest always use `module.exports` in your module definitions.

I don't completely understand what's going on internally with Node, but please comment if you can make more sense of this as I'm sure it helps.

-- Happy coding

Comment: I think they are unnecessarily complicated and confusing. It should be transparent and intuitive.

Comment: I agree. It may be useful for namespacing is some circumstances, but is generally not going to make or break anything.

Answer (score 4):

I found this link useful to answer the above question.

http://timnew.me/blog/2012/04/20/exports-vs-module-exports-in-node-js/

To add to the other posts  The module system in node does

```
var exports = module.exports
```

before executing your code. So when you want to exports = foo  , you probably want to do module.exports = exports = foo  but using exports.foo = foo should be fine

Answer (score 4):

This shows how `require()` works in its simplest form, excerpted from [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/)

**Problem**
It is not possible for a module to directly export a value other than the exports object, such as a function. For example, a module might want to export only the constructor of the object type it defines. Right now, it cannot do that because require always uses the `exports` object it creates as the exported value.

**Solution**
Provide modules with another variable, `module`, which is an object that has a property `exports`. This property initially points at the empty object created by require but can be overwritten with another value in order to export something else.

```
function require(name) {
  if (name in require.cache)
    return require.cache[name];
  var code = new Function("exports, module", readFile(name));
  var exports = {}, module = {exports: exports};
  code(exports, module);
  require.cache[name] = module.exports;
  return module.exports;
}
require.cache = Object.create(null);
```

Comment: I had to recreate this in Node and test a few things until I got, I suck. Basically, the inner function created for the module never even returns the exports object. So the "exports" object isn't actually reassigned in the module e.g. if you try to write exports = "this is now a string" directly. The object only exists as a reference. This is behaviour I don't think I've really picked up on properly until now.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the result of

```
console.log("module:");
console.log(module);

console.log("exports:");
console.log(exports);

console.log("module.exports:");
console.log(module.exports);
```

[image]

Also:

```
if(module.exports === exports){
    console.log("YES");
}else{
    console.log("NO");
}

//YES
```

Note:
The CommonJS specification only allows the use of the exports variable to expose public members. Therefore, the named exports pattern is the only one that is really compatible with the CommonJS specification. The use of module.exports is an extension provided by Node.js to support a broader range of module definition patterns.

Answer (score 4):

```
var a = {},md={};
```

//Firstly,the exports and module.exports point the same empty Object

```
exp = a;//exports =a;
md.exp = a;//module.exports = a;

exp.attr = "change";

console.log(md.exp);//{attr:"change"}
```

//If you point exp to other object instead of point it's property to other object. The md.exp will be empty Object {}

```
var a ={},md={};
exp =a;
md.exp =a;

exp = function(){ console.log('Do nothing...'); };

console.log(md.exp); //{}
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html)

> The exports variable is available within a module's file-level scope, and is assigned the value of module.exports before the module is evaluated.
>
> **It allows a shortcut, so that module.exports.f = ... can be written more succinctly as exports.f = ....** However, be aware that like any variable, if a new value is assigned to exports, it is no longer bound to module.exports:

*It is just a variable pointing to module.exports.*

Answer (score 4):

`module.exports` and `exports` both point to the same object before the module is evaluated.

Any property you add to the `module.exports`  object will be available when your module is used in another module using `require` statement. `exports` is a shortcut made available for the same thing. For instance:

```js
module.exports.add = (a, b) => a+b
```

is equivalent to writing:

```js
exports.add = (a, b) => a+b
```

So it is okay as long as you do not assign a new value to `exports` variable. When you do something like this:

```js
exports = (a, b) => a+b
```

as you are assigning a new value to `exports` it no longer has reference to the exported object and thus will remain local to your module.

If you are planning to assign a new value to `module.exports` rather than adding new properties to the initial object made available, you should probably consider doing as given below:

```js
module.exports = exports = (a, b) => a+b
```

[Node.js website has a very good explanation of this.](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports)

Answer (score 3):

"If you want the root of your module's export to be a function (such as a constructor) or if you want to export a complete object in one assignment instead of building it one property at a time, assign it to module.exports instead of exports." - http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Answer (score 3):

Let's create one module with 2 ways:

One way

```
var aa = {
    a: () => {return 'a'},
    b: () => {return 'b'}
}

module.exports = aa;
```

Second way

```
exports.a = () => {return 'a';}
exports.b = () => {return 'b';}
```

And this is how *require()* will integrate module.

First way:

```
function require(){
    module.exports = {};
    var exports = module.exports;

    var aa = {
        a: () => {return 'a'},
        b: () => {return 'b'}
    }
    module.exports = aa;

    return module.exports;
}
```

Second way

```
function require(){
    module.exports = {};
    var exports = module.exports;

    exports.a = () => {return 'a';}
    exports.b = () => {return 'b';}

    return module.exports;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1.exports -> use as singleton utility 
2. module-exports -> use as logical objects such as service , model etc

Answer (score 2):

> why both are used here

I believe they just want to be clear that `module.exports`, `exports`, and `nano` point to the same function - allowing you to use either variable to call the function within the file. `nano` provides some context to what the function does.

*`exports` won't be exported (only `module.exports` will), so why bother overwriting that as well?*

The verbosity trade-off limits the risk of future bugs, such as using `exports` instead of `module.exports` within the file. It also provides **clarification** that `module.exports` and `exports` are in fact pointing to the same value.

---

#### `module.exports` vs `exports`

As long as you don't reassign `module.exports` or `exports` (and instead add values to the object they both refer to), you won't have any issues and can safely use `exports` to be more concise.

When assigning either to a non-object, they are now pointing to different places which can be confusing unless you intentionally want `module.exports` to be something specific (such as a function).

Setting `exports` to a non-object doesn't make much sense as you'll have to set `module.exports = exports` at the end to be able to use it in other files.

```
let module = { exports: {} };
let exports = module.exports;

exports.msg = 'hi';
console.log(module.exports === exports); // true

exports = 'yo';
console.log(module.exports === exports); // false

exports = module.exports;
console.log(module.exports === exports); // true

module.exports = 'hello';
console.log(module.exports === exports); // false

module.exports = exports;
console.log(module.exports === exports); // true
```

#### Why assign `module.exports` to a function?

More concise! Compare how much shorter the 2nd example is:

helloWorld1.js: `module.exports.hello = () => console.log('hello world');`

app1.js: `let sayHello = require('./helloWorld1'); sayHello.hello; // hello world`

helloWorld2.js: `module.exports = () => console.log('hello world');`

app2.js: `let sayHello = require('./helloWorld2'); sayHello; // hello world`

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Each file you create is a module. module is an object. It has property called `exports : {}` which is empty object by default.

you can create functions/middlewares and add  to this empty exports object such as `exports.findById() => { ...  }`  then `require` anywhere in your app and use...

**controllers/user.js**

```
exports.findById = () => {
    //  do something
}
```

require in **routes.js** to use:

```
const {findyId} = './controllers/user'
```

Answer (score 1):

- **exports**: it's a reference to module.exports object
- both **exports** and **module.exports** point to the same object
  until we change the reference of **exports** object

**Example:**

1. if exports.a = 10 then module.exports.a = 10
2. if we reassign exports object explicitly inside the code like
   exports = {} now its lost the reference to module.exports

Answer (score 0):

in node js module.js file is use to run the module.load system.every time when node execute a file it wrap your js file content as follow

```
'(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {',+
     //your js file content
 '\n});'
```

because of this wrapping inside ur js source code you can access exports,require,module,etc..
this approach is used because there is no other way to get functionalities wrote in on js file to another.

then node execute this wrapped function using c++. at that moment exports object that passed into this function will be filled.

you can see inside this function parameters exports and module.
actually exports is a public member of module constructor function.

**look at following code**

copy this code into b.js

```
console.log("module is "+Object.prototype.toString.call(module));
console.log("object.keys "+Object.keys(module));
console.log(module.exports);
console.log(exports === module.exports);
console.log("exports is "+Object.prototype.toString.call(exports));
console.log('----------------------------------------------');
var foo = require('a.js');
console.log("object.keys of foo: "+Object.keys(foo));
console.log('name is '+ foo);
foo();
```

copy this code to a.js

```
exports.name = 'hello';
module.exports.name = 'hi';
module.exports.age = 23;
module.exports = function(){console.log('function to module exports')};
//exports = function(){console.log('function to export');}
```

now run using node

### this is the output

```
module is [object Object]
object.keys id,exports,parent,filename,loaded,children,paths
{}
true
```

### exports is [object Object]

object.keys of foo: 
name is function (){console.log('function to module exports')}
function to module exports

now remove the commented line in a.js and comment the line above that line
and remove the last line of b.js and run.

in javascript world you cannot reassign object that passed as parameter but you can change function's public member when object of that function set as a parameter to another function

### do remember

use module.exports on and only if you wants to get a function when you use require keyword .
in above example we var foo = require(a.js); you can see we can call foo as a function;

this is how node documentation explain it
"The exports object is created by the Module system. Sometimes this is not acceptable, many want their module to be an instance of some class. To do this assign the desired export object to module.exports."

Answer (score 0):

1. > Both `module.exports` and `exports` point to the same `function database_module(cfg) {...}`.

   ```
   1| var a, b;
   2| a = b = function() { console.log("Old"); };
   3|     b = function() { console.log("New"); };
   4|
   5| a(); // "Old"
   6| b(); // "New"
   ```

   You can change `b` on line 3 to `a`, the output is reverse. The conclusion is:

   > `a` and `b` are independent.
2. So `module.exports = exports = nano = function database_module(cfg) {...}` is equivalent to:

   ```
   var f = function database_module(cfg) {...};
   module.exports = f;
   exports = f;
   ```

   Assumed the above is `module.js`, which is required by `foo.js`. The benefits of `module.exports = exports = nano = function database_module(cfg) {...}` is clear now:

   - In `foo.js`, since `module.exports` is `require('./module.js')`:

     ```
     var output = require('./modules.js')();
     ```
   - In `moduls.js`: You can use `exports` instead of `module.exports`.

So, you will be happy if both `exports` and `module.exports` pointing to the same thing.