# Why doesn't backbone use module.exports?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

It looks like it uses just plain

`exports` instead of `module.exports`

in this line [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L32).

```
if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    Backbone = exports;
```

However this [tutorial](http://openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/) shows the `module.exports` being used.

Comment: `exports` and `module.exports` are the same.

Comment: ... not sure if this is related ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-nodejs  ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-nodejs-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it

Comment: Looks like module is the global variable. Kind of like window is the global variable when on the browser/client. Why then is the code not Backbone = root.exports. In this case, root will point to module. global to each file. or local to each file. however you want to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't backbone use module.exports?

Because it doesn't have to. [`exports` and `module.exports` refer to the same object](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_module):

> In particular `module.exports`is the same as the `exports` object.

If you can save a couple of characters to type, then why not do it?

You are doing the same when you use `document.getElementById` instead of `window.document.getElementById`. It's more to type and doesn't add any benefit.

---

In the tutorial they are using `module.exports` because they want to show the difference between exporting a symbol why `exports`, i.e.

```
exports.foo = bar;
```

and *overwriting* the `exports` object

```
module.exports = bar;
```

for which you *have to* use `module.exports` (`exports = bar;` would not work).

Answer (score 1):

Think of `module` like `window` in a browser. In actuality, they're basically the same thing.

So, in the same way that `window.location === location` in javascript executed in the browser, `module.exports === exports` in a node environment.