# How to run QUnit tests from command line?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, continuous-integration, qunit

I recently started working on a Rails app that has a large amount of QUnit tests already in place for testing ember. I have been charged with the task of setting the app with a CI (I decided to use CodeShip). The issue I currently face is that the only way for me to run the qunit tests is to go to `http://localhost:3000/qunit`. I need to setup a way to run the tests from the command line. I have done a large amount of research, and have tried at least 10 different solutions but non have managed to work.

Currently I am attempting to use [teaspoon](https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon) but it I have not managed to get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated. Please let me know if I need to post more information about the setup.

Answer (score 9):

[node-qunit-phantomjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-qunit-phantomjs) gets the job done easy enough and is standalone, not a Grunt-, Gulp-, whatever-plugin:

```
$ npm install -g node-qunit-phantomjs

$ node-qunit-phantomjs tests.html
Testing tests.html
Took 8 ms to run 1 tests. 0 passed, 1 failed.
...
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: I get an error when I try to run the tests "Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode" Do you have an idea?

Comment: PhantomJS is based on an old version of webkit and is no longer being maintained. It will raise deprecation warnings/errors when being used in Selenium, for example.

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR

Use out-of-the-box `qunit` command (do `npm install -g qunit` beforehand), so you don't need additional dependencies.

---

Extending a bit Arthur's answer because he mentioned only simplest case which works only for simplest projects.

As mentioned on [QUnit](https://qunitjs.com/) page, there is built-in possibility to run tests from command line. **There is no need to install additional weird frameworks on top of QUnit!**

```
npm install -g qunit
qunit # Will search for tests in "test" directory
```

This works for artificial tests as on their website, but in real project you probably will have your logic in some other .js file.

Having following structure:

```
project
│   index.js <--- Your script with logic
│   package.json <--- most probably you'll have npm file since qunit executable is installed via npm
└───test
        tests.html <--- QUnit tests included in standard HTML page for "running" locally
        tests.js <--- QUnit test code
```

And let's imagine that in your `index.js` you have following:

```
function doSomething(arg) {
  // do smth
  return arg;
}
```

And the test code in `tests.js` (not that it can be the *whole* content of the file - you don't need anything else to work):

```
QUnit.test( "test something", function( assert ) {
  assert.ok(doSomething(true));
});
```

**Running in browser**

This is not related directly to the question, but just want to make a reference here.
Just put both your script and tests to tests.html and open the page in browser:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../index.js"></script>`

`<script src="tests.js"></script>`

**Running from command line**

With the setup described below you can try to run `qunit`, but it will not work because it cannot find your function `doSomething`. To make it accessible you need to add two things to the scripts.

First is to explicitly "import" your script from tests. Since JS doesn't have sunch a functionality out-of-the box, we'll need to use `require` coming from NPM. And to keep our tests working from HTML (when you run it from browser, `require` is undefined) add simple check:

```
// Add this in the beginning of tests.js
// Use "require" only if run from command line
if (typeof(require) !== 'undefined') {
    // It's important to define it with the very same name in order to have both browser and CLI runs working with the same test code
    doSomething = require('../index.js').doSomething;
}
```

But if `index.js` does not expose anything, nothing will be accessible. So it's required to expose functions you want to test explicitly (read more about [exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js)). Add this to index.js:

```
//This goes to the very bottom of index.js
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
  exports.doSomething = doSomething; 
}
```

When it's done, first check tests.html still working and not raising any errors (testing test infrastructure, yeah) and, finaly, try

```
qunit
```

And the output should be like

```
TAP version 13
ok 1 Testing index.js > returnTrue returns true
1..1
# pass 1
# skip 0
# todo 0
# fail 0
```

**I don't want to deal with node for my simple (or not) project**

This is an open question and I cannot answer this. But you'll need *some* runner to run QUnit tests anyway. So maybe having `package.json` with one devDependency like `"qunit": "^2.6.1"` is not the worst option here. There are several 3rd-party runners: [grunt-qunit](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-qunit), [PhantomJS runnner](https://github.com/jonkemp/qunit-phantomjs-runner), [ember-qunit-cli](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-qunit), also see more on official [QUnit Plugins page](https://qunitjs.com/plugins/)

**What if I have class, not function?**

In JS everything is a function, right :)? So no problem, just change your script exports and tests import acordingly

```
exports.exportedMyClass = MyClass; // in index.js
MyClass= require('../index.js').exportedMyClass ; // in tests.js
```

See example a.k.a. small getting started [here](https://github.com/okainov/qunit-getting-stated).

Answer (score 2):

[QUnit now has its own CLI](https://qunitjs.com/):

```
$ npm install -g qunit
$ qunit 'tests/*-test.js'
TAP version 13
ok 1 Module > Test #1
ok 2 Module > Test #2
1..2
# pass 2
# skip 0
# todo 0
# fail 0
```

Run `qunit --help` for more usage information.

Comment: Problem here is that I need my project script to be imported. SO in HTML you do it in a pretty easy way: include your script, include test script, use your functions in tests script. However when you run in via this command-line, there will be errors "undefined function myProjectFunction" - because it doesn't know where to get your project script.

Comment: @TheGodfather Yes, that's true, and something I've been struggling with myself. I think this method of running QUnit is most easily done when you're already using Node's [`require()`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require) function to import your modules, which is a bit of a problem if you're wanting to test a non-Node project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) (task runner) for this. You would also need to install these two packages: [grunt-contrib-qunit](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-qunit) and [grunt-contrib-connect](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-connect)

I did just recently set up a GitHub repository when trying to figure out how to run QUnit on Travis CI: https://github.com/stebru/travis-qunit-test

You're welcome to fork it and try it out for yourself.

Comment: Let me know if you need any help with setting up grunt.