# How to run several QUnit (node.js) test files using a single command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, tdd, qunit

### Scenario

We are trying to use the [**Node.js QUnit Module** aka ***qunitjs***](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qunitjs) for our Server-Side Testing so that we can write one test and run it on both server and client e.g: https://github.com/nelsonic/learn-tdd/blob/master/test.js

When we run a single file using the command:

`node test/my_test.js`

It works as expected.

However, when we have more than one test in a [/**test**](https://github.com/nelsonic/hapi-socketio-redis-chat-example/tree/master/test) *directory* and try to run all the files as a *suite* using the following command:

`node test/*.js`

only the *first* file (*alphabetically*) gets executed.

see: https://github.com/nelsonic/hapi-socketio-redis-chat-example/tree/master/test

### Question

> ***How** do we **execute multiple test files** with a **single command***?

We *tried* to dig through existing StackOverflow + GitHub Q/A for this but did not find any match. (*any suggestions/help much appreciated!*)

Answer (score 0):

QUnit has command-line runner out-of-the-box, so just run:

```
npm install -g qunit
qunit
```

It will search for tests in `test` folder by default automatically and execute all of them.  Also you may specify test scripts manually `qunit test/only_this_test.js test/also_this_test.js`

**It's running, but tests are failing!**

If the failure is related to undefined functions, that's because you need to tell your tests how to find your functions-under-test.

Modify tests.js:

```
// Add this in the beginning of tests.js
// Use "require" only if run from command line
if (typeof(require) !== 'undefined') {
    // It's important to define it with the very same name in order to have both browser and CLI runs working with the same test code
    doSomething = require('../index.js').doSomething;
}
```

Modify your js scripts:

```
//This goes to the very bottom of index.js
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
  exports.doSomething = doSomething; 
}
```

See more details in my other answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51861149/1657819

P.S. Nice tutorial in the repo! ;)