# Node.js export variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a Node.js module and I need to pass variable data from the main file to the functions. I am doing this:

```
var region;
var api_key;

exports.region = region;
exports.api_key = api_key;


module.exports = {

  getSummonerId: function(sum, callback) {

    var summoners = {};
    var summoner = sum.replace(/\s+/g, '');

    request("https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + region + "/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + summoner + "?api_key=" + api_key, function(error, response, body) {
      summoners[summoner] = JSON.parse(body);
      callback(summoners[summoner][summoner].id);
    });
  }
}
```

And in the **main file**:

```
var lol = require('./apiwrapper.js');

lol.api_key = "example";
lol.region  = "las";


lol.getChampions(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
})
```

But from **apiwrapper.js** file, those two variables' value are always "**undefined**".

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-nodejs?rq=1

Comment: You cann't use `exports.region` and `module.exports` at the same time.

Comment: What is `getChampions`?

Comment: and if I do module.exports.region?

Answer (score 13):

The value that is imported to the other module is `module.exports`. So, what you assign to `module.exports` is exported. Whatever was assigned earlier to it is lost.

The relation between `module.exports` and `exports` is that they refer to the same object initially:

```
var exports = module.exports = {};
```

So, assigning a property to either of them mutates the same object. However, you are assigning a new object to `module.exports`, so now both of them reference different objects.

A simple solution is to assign the new object to `exports` as well and then assign the other properties:

```
exports = module.exports = {...};
exports.region = region;
```

If you want to keep the order of the statements, then you have to extend the default exports object, instead of creating a new one:

```
Object.assign(exports, { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
module.exports = {
  region: my_region,
  api_key: my_api_key,
  getSummonerId: function(sum, callback) {

    var summoners = {};
    var summoner = sum.replace(/\s+/g, '');

    request("https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + region + "/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + summoner + "?api_key=" + api_key, function(error, response, body) {
          summoners[summoner] = JSON.parse(body);
          callback(summoners[summoner][summoner].id);
    });
  }
}
```

In your case, "module.exports" is overwriting the previously exported variables. Which is the reason you are getting undefined for those.

Comment: yup, exactly. Just try it!