# Closing server after mocha test, but data is still there

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js

I'm trying to test some data through a REST API. The data is stored as an array in the project.

I want the data to be "restored" every time a test suites runs, so that i know the amount of data in the array.

But when im testing the post. The element that is inserted is there in the next test suite, even though i start and stop the server before each test.

app.js requires the user array, so by stopping and starting the server, i thought i would be clean before every test, but it doesn't

Thansk .

```
 global.test = true;

    // Test server setup
    var app = require('../app');
    var testPort = 9999;
    var testServer;

    // Dependencies
    var should = require('should');
    var request = require('request');

    var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:9999/api';

    describe('RESTApi : GET Methods', function () {
        //Start the Server before the TESTS
        beforeEach(function (done) {

            testServer = app.listen(testPort, function () {
                console.log("Server is listening on: " + testPort);
                done();
            })
                .on('error', function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        });

        afterEach(function () {  //Stop server after the test
            testServer.close(function () {
                console.log("closing server");
            });
        });

     TEST here           

    });

    describe('RESTApi : POST Methods', function () {
        //Start the Server before the TESTS
        before(function (done) {

            testServer = app.listen(testPort, function () {
                console.log("Server is listening on: " + testPort);
                done();
            })
                .on('error', function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        });

        after(function () {  //Stop server after the test
            testServer.close(function () {
                console.log("closing server");
            });
        });

       TEST here

    });
```

------ App.js -----
I know the REST api should be in its own folder. :)

```
var path = require('path');
        var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

        //For testing to delete the cached user array
        delete require.cache[require.resolve('./users')];

        var users = require('./users');
        var express = require('express');

        function findUser(users, email) {
            var result = users.filter(function(u) {
                return u.email === email;
            });
            if(result.length >= 1) {
                return result[0];
            }
            return undefined;
        }

        var app = express();

        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


        app.get("/api/users", function(req, res) {
            res.send(users);
        });

        app.get("/api/users/:email", function(req, res) {
            var user = findUser(users, req.params.email);
            if(!user) {
                return res.status(404).send({error: "user not found"});
            }
            res.send(user);
        });

        app.post("/api/users", function(req, res) {
            var user = req.body;
            if(findUser(users, user.email)) {
                return res.status(400).send({error: "user exist"});
            }
            users.push(user);
            res.send(user);
        });

        app.put("/api/users/:email", function(req, res) {
            var user = req.body;
            if(!findUser(users, req.params.email)) {
                return res.status(404).send({error: "user not found"});
            }
            if(!user) {
                return res.status(404).send({error: "no user provided"});
            }
            for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i += 1) {
                if(users[i].email === user.email) {
                    users[i].password = user.password;
                    break;
                }
            }
            res.send(user);
        });

        app.delete("/api/users/:email", function(req, res) {
            var user = findUser(users, req.params.email);
            if(!user) {
                return res.status(404).send({error: "user not found"});
            }
            for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                if(users[i].email === req.params.email) {
                    users.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            res.send(user);
        });

        app.all('*', function(req, res) {
            res.status(500).send(req.url + " not a valid");
        });

        if(global.activeTest === undefined){
            app.listen(3000, function() {
                console.log("Rest API started, listen on port 3000");
            });
        }

        module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Can you show `app.js`?

Comment: Sure, its added. I tried removing the cashed data and that worked. But if there is a better way let me know :)

Comment: Thanks for adding the `app.js` code. Removing the cached required users really worked? It doesn't make sense to me, but I can't argue with you if you actually tried/tested it. I was going to propose a different solution involving refactoring the code that initialized the `user` var in to a function and exposing it so that you can "re-initialize" it before each test. I'll post my proposed solution shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution (as I mentioned in my comment above) would be to refactor the code that initializes the `users` var into a separate function, that can be called before each test.

```
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var clone = require('clone'); // <-- add `clone` as a dependency

var users;
function initUsers() {
  users = clone(require('./users'));
}

// ... the rest if your code, initializing express/adding route handlers

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Rest API started, listen on port 3000");
});

module.exports = exports = app;
exports.initUsers = initUsers;
```

Using this as my sample data in `users.js`:

```
module.exports = [
  { email: 'email0', password: 'password0' },
  { email: 'email1', password: 'password1' },
  { email: 'email2', password: 'password2' },
  { email: 'email3', password: 'password3' },
  { email: 'email4', password: 'password4' },
  { email: 'email5', password: 'password5' },
  { email: 'email6', password: 'password6' },
  { email: 'email7', password: 'password7' },
  { email: 'email8', password: 'password8' },
  { email: 'email9', password: 'password9' }
];
```

I was able to successfully test by calling `initUsers()` before each test, as follows:

```
var app = require('../app');
var initUsers = require('../app').initUsers;

var should = require('should');
var request = require('request');

var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api';

describe('RESTApi', function() {

  describe('GET Methods', function () {

    beforeEach(function() {
      initUsers();
    });

    it('should get all users initially', function(done) {
      request(baseUrl + '/users', function(err, res) {
        var data = JSON.parse(res.body);
        data.length.should.equal(10);
        done();
      });
    });

    it('should remove user', function(done) {
      request.del(baseUrl + '/users/email1', function(err, res) {
        var data = JSON.parse(res.body);
        data.email.should.equal('email1');
        data.password.should.equal('password1');

        request(baseUrl + '/users', function(err, res) {
          var data = JSON.parse(res.body);
          data.length.should.equal(9);
          done();
        });

      });
    });

    it('should get all users again', function(done) {
      request(baseUrl + '/users', function(err, res) {
        var data = JSON.parse(res.body);
        data.length.should.equal(10);
        done();
      });
    });

  });

});
```

As you can see, I wrote three tests.

1. get all users (verifying the initial count is 10)
2. removing a user (verifying the count is now 9)
3. get all users (verifying count is now 10 again)

These are, by no means, exhaustive tests, but they verify that `users` is being properly initialized before every test.

Comment: Just what i was looking for, thanks alot!. In your version of app.js you use module.exports = exports = app; What the difference between that and module.exports = app;

Comment: Your welcome. The `module.exports`/`exports` issue is beyond the scope of this question. If you want the technical difference check out the [NodeJS doc](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports). Also, the question has already be asked/answered in stackoverflow, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `app.listen()` is asynchronous, so your tests continue to run regardless of whether the server is stopped. I would put your tests inside the `callback` parameter.