# Create a NodeJS module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make a simple NodeJS module with the following pattern:`module.exports = function () {}`.
My problem is that when I write `exports.myFunc = myFunc;` it works well, but when I write `module.exports = myFunc;` it doesn't work.

Here's some of my code snippets:

**function.js:**

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var i = 0;

function getFilesByExtArgs (dir, ext){
    fs.readdir(dir, function (err, data){
                while (i <= data.length){
                    if (path.extname(data[i]) == ('.' + ext))
                        console.log(data[i]);
                    i++;
                }
        });
}

exports.getFilesByExtArgs = getFilesByExtArgs;
```

**module.js:**

```
var myModule = require('./listFilesByExtArgs');

myModule.getFilesByExtArgs(process.argv[2], process.argv[3]);
```

How can I make my code work with the pattern needed ?

Comment: 8-space indentation? Eww...

Comment: @GabrielTomitsuka Auto indented by Emacs..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of different behaviors of `module.exports` and `exports.property`. So when your write `module.exports = myFunc;` you actiually make a full module as a func. It uses following way:

```
var myModule = require('./listFilesByExtArgs');
// In mymodule is actually alias to a func listFilesByExtArgs
myModule(process.argv[2], process.argv[3]);
```

A full answer you can found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js).

Answer (score 1):

```
module.exports = myFunc
```

exports the myFunc function as the module while

```
exports.myFunc = myFunc
```

exports the myFunc function as a myFunc property of the exported module.

so you either use

```
// case: module.exports = myFunc
var myModule = require('myModule');
myModule();
```

or

```
// case: exports.myFunc = myFunc
var myModule = require('myModule');
myModule.myFunc();
```