# How to properly export from required node file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been reading about Node's `require` and how its [`exports` is automatically overridden when a `module.exports` has data or functionality declared within it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26451885/1252748). So let me see if I understand correctly: anything that I put in exports will be included in files which require the file.

I have inherited some node files, one main file with heaps of `require`s, and each required file with the structure:

```
var obj = {};
obj.prop1 = "some value1";
obj.prop2 = "some value2";    
module.exports = exports = obj;
```

Is this a standard way of exporting data in a required file? Is it sensible to a)declare this (seemingly redundant `obj`)? ,b)if no functionality is being assigned to either `exports` or `module.exports`, why do they both need to be pointed at `obj`? c)what is the purpose of this middle-level `exports` if it can be overridden? What is the use case for both of these objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the purpose of this middle-level `exports` if it can be overridden?

`exports` is initially set to the value of `module.exports` and is available as a convenience (and default value), so that you don't have to create your own object to export values. Your example is basically equivalent to just using:

```
exports.prop1 = "some value1";
exports.prop2 = "some value2";
```

> if no functionality is being assigned to either `exports` or `module.exports`, why do they both need to be pointed at `obj`

If you want to export `obj` from the module, you have to assign it to `module.exports`. That's how Node knows which value to return when the module is `required`.

The assignment to `exports` is not really necessary, but it can prevents mistake like

```
module.exports = {foo: 42};
// now `module.exports` and `exports` point to different objects
// the following export is just "lost" (ignored)
exports.bar = 21;
```

The assignments (`module.exports = exports = ...`) ensures that both, `module.exports` and `exports` point to the same object so mutations via either variable have an effect.

> Is it sensible to declare this (seemingly redundant `obj`)

There multiple ways to achieve what you want. I showed one at the top using `exports` directly. You could also just write

```
module.exports = {
  prop1: "some value1",
  prop2: "some value2" 
};
```

Use whatever makes sense to you and complies with the style guidelines you are following.

---

At the end of the day, the value you want to export must be assigned to `module.exports`. *How* you do that is up to you.